# Dictionary merge by updating but not overwriting if value exists

Tags: python, dictionary, merge, compare

If I have 2 dicts as follows:

```
d1 = {'a': 2, 'b': 4}
d2 = {'a': 2, 'b': ''}
```

In order to 'merge' them:

```
dict(d1.items() + d2.items())
```

results in

```
{'a': 2, 'b': ''}
```

But what should I do if I would like to compare each value of the two dictionaries and only update `d2` into `d1` if values in `d1` are empty/`None`/`''`?

When the same key exists, I would like to only maintain the numerical value (either from `d1` or `d2`) instead of the empty value. If both values are empty, then no problems maintaining the empty value. If both have values, then `d1`-value should stay.

i.e.

```
d1 = {'a': 2, 'b': 8, 'c': ''}
d2 = {'a': 2, 'b': '', 'c': ''}
```

should result in

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 8, 'c': ''}
```

where 8 is not overwritten by `''`.

Comment: Have you tried `in` yet?

Comment: **See also** (php-based) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793464/php-array-merge-without-erasing-values

Comment: **See also** (ruby-based) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980794/how-can-i-merge-two-hashes-without-overwritten-duplicate-keys-in-ruby

Comment: **See also:** (itemgetter) https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118794/42223

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Just switch the order:

```
z = dict(d2.items() + d1.items())
```

By the way, you may also be interested in the potentially faster [`update`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) method.

In Python 3, you have to cast the view objects to lists first:

```
z = dict(list(d2.items()) + list(d1.items()))
```

If you want to special-case empty strings, you can do the following:

```
def mergeDictsOverwriteEmpty(d1, d2):
    res = d2.copy()
    for k,v in d2.items():
        if k not in d1 or d1[k] == '':
            res[k] = v
    return res
```

Comment: i think, in this case.. if `d1` has empty item-value it would overwrite `d2` item-value which has numerical value?

Comment: @siva Updated with your special case.

Comment: I'm thinking that should be `res=d1.copy()`, otherwise there is no information transfer between the dicts.

Comment: Python 3.4.3, at least, does not support `+` between dictionary items sets, *but* you can achieve the same results by casting to `list`: `dict(list(d2.items()) + list(d1.items()))`

Comment: `itertools.chain()` may also help.

Comment: In Python 3, you can just do `z = {**d2, **d1}`.

Answer (score 30):

Updates `d2` with `d1` key/value pairs, but only if `d1` value is not `None`, `''` (False):

```
>>> d1 = dict(a=1, b=None, c=2)
>>> d2 = dict(a=None, b=2, c=1)
>>> d2.update({k: v for k, v in d1.items() if v})
>>> d2
{'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 2}
```

(Use `iteritems()` instead of `items()` in Python 2.)

Comment: ... which will change the input `d2`. Why not `dr={}; dr.update(d1); dr.update((k,v) for (k,v) in d2.items() if v)` ?

Comment: That worked for me `d2.update({k:v for k,v in d1.iteritems() if v is not None})`

Comment: I think the more suitable variation would be:
`d1.update({k: v for k, v in d2.items() if not k in d1})`

Answer (score 10):

To add to `d2` keys/values from `d1` which do not exist in `d2` without overwriting any existing keys/values in `d2`:

```
temp = d2.copy()
d2.update(d1)
d2.update(temp)
```

Answer (score 9):

## Python 3.5+ Literal Dict

unless using obsolete version of python you better off using this.

Pythonic & faster way for dict unpacking:

```
d1 = {'a':1, 'b':1}
d2 = {'a':2, 'c':2}
merged = {**d1, **d2}  # priority from right to left
print(merged)

{'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
```

its simpler and also faster than the `dict(list(d2.items()) + list(d1.items()))` alternative:

```
d1 = {i: 1 for i in range(1000000)}
d2 = {i: 2 for i in range(2000000)}

%timeit dict(list(d1.items()) + list(d2.items())) 
402 ms ± 33.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit {**d1, **d2}
144 ms ± 1.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

more on this from [PEP448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/):

> The keys in a dictionary remain in a right-to-left priority order, so {**{'a': 1}, 'a': 2, **{'a': 3}} evaluates to {'a': 3}. There is no restriction on the number or position of unpackings.

## Merging Only Non-zero values

to do this we can just create a dict without the empty values and then merge them together this way:

```
d1 = {'a':1, 'b':1, 'c': '', 'd': ''}
d2 = {'a':2, 'c':2, 'd': ''}
merged_non_zero = {
    k: (d1.get(k) or d2.get(k))
    for k in set(d1) | set(d2)
}
print(merged_non_zero)
```

outputs:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': ''}
```

- `a` -> prefer first value from d1 as 'a' exists on both d1 and d2
- `b` -> only exists on d1
- `c` -> non-zero on d2
- `d` -> empty string on both

### Explanation

The above code will create a dictionary using dict comprehension.

if `d1` has the value and its non-zero value (i.e. `bool(val) is True`), it'll use `d1[k]` value, otherwise it'll take `d2[k]`.

notice that we also merge all keys of the two dicts as they may not have the exact same keys using set union - `set(d1) | set(d2)`.

Comment: This answer is flat out wrong unless you do it as `{**d2, **d1}`. You still need to reverse the dictionaries if you don't want `d2` to overwrite values in `d1`.

Comment: thanks @drhagen i've updated it to include better answer together with my suggestion on how to merge

Comment: just drop everything above Python 3.5 please.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an **in-place** solution (it modifies d2):

```
# assumptions: d2 is a temporary dict that can be discarded
# d1 is a dict that must be modified in place
# the modification is adding keys from d2 into d1 that do not exist in d1.

def update_non_existing_inplace(original_dict, to_add):
    to_add.update(original_dict) # to_add now holds the "final result" (O(n))
    original_dict.clear() # erase original_dict in-place (O(1))
    original_dict.update(to_add) # original_dict now holds the "final result" (O(n))
    return
```

Here's another **in-place** solution, which is less elegant but potentially more efficient, as well as **leaving d2 unmodified**:

```
# assumptions: d2 is can not be modified
# d1 is a dict that must be modified in place
# the modification is adding keys from d2 into d1 that do not exist in d1.

def update_non_existing_inplace(original_dict, to_add):
    for key in to_add.iterkeys():
        if key not in original_dict:
            original_dict[key] = to_add[key]
```

Answer (score 5):

`d2.update(d1)` instead of `dict(d2.items() + d1.items())`

Comment: ... would change the content of `d2` which might not be what the OP want. At least, the `dict(d1.items()+d2.items())` keeps the inputs unchanged.

Answer (score 4):

In case when you have dictionaries with the same size and keys you can use the following code:

```
dict((k,v if k in d2 and d2[k] in [None, ''] else d2[k]) for k,v in d1.iteritems())
```

Comment: unfortunately, my dictionaries are not some size and keys, only some occurence of the same keys with diff values.

Comment: @siva: i have modified code to check d2 on key from d1 if this is your case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore empty spaces so that for example merging:

```py
a = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": ""}
b = {"a": "", "b": 4, "c": 5}
c = {"a": "aaa", "b": ""}
d = {"a": "", "w": ""}
```

results in:`{'a': 'aaa', 'b': 4, 'c': 5, 'w': ''}`

You can use these 2 functions:

```py
def merge_two_dicts(a, b, path=None):
    "merges b into a"
    if path is None:
        path = []
    for key in b:
        if key in a:
            if isinstance(a[key], dict) and isinstance(b[key], dict):
                merge_two_dicts(a[key], b[key], path + [str(key)])
            elif a[key] == b[key]:
                pass  # same leaf value
            else:
                if a[key] and not b[key]:
                    a[key] = a[key]
                else:
                    a[key] = b[key]
        else:
            a[key] = b[key]
    return a


def merge_multiple_dicts(*a):
    output = a[0]
    if len(a) >= 2:
        for n in range(len(a) - 1):
            output = merge_two_dicts(output, a[n + 1])

    return output
```

So you can just use `merge_multiple_dicts(a,b,c,d)`

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution if you want to have more freedom to choose when a value should be overwritten in the merged dictionary. Maybe it's a verbose script, but it's not hard to understand its logic.

Thanks **fabiocaccamo** and **senderle** for sharing the [benedict package](https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/python-benedict), and the [nested iteration logic in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10756615/16109419), respectively. This knowledge was fundamental to the script development.

#### Python Requirements

```
pip install python-benedict==0.24.3
```

#### Python Script

Definition of the `Dict` class.

```
from __future__ import annotations

from collections.abc import Mapping
from benedict import benedict
from typing import Iterator
from copy import deepcopy


class Dict:
    def __init__(self, data: dict = None):
        """
        Instantiates a dictionary object with nested keys-based indexing.

        Parameters
        ----------
        data: dict
            Dictionary.

        References
        ----------
        [1] 'Dict' class: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70908985/16109419
        [2] 'Benedict' package: https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/python-benedict
        [3] Dictionary nested iteration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10756615/16109419
        """
        self.data = deepcopy(data) if data is not None else {}

    def get(self, keys: [object], **kwargs) -> (object, bool):
        """
        Get dictionary item value based on nested keys.

        Parameters
        ----------
        keys: [object]
            Nested keys to get item value based on.

        Returns
        -------
        value, found: (object, bool)
            Item value, and whether the target item was found.
        """
        data = kwargs.get('data', self.data)
        path = kwargs.get('path', [])
        value, found = None, False

        # Looking for item location on dictionary:
        for outer_key, outer_value in data.items():
            trace = path + [outer_key]

            # Getting item value from dictionary:
            if trace == keys:
                value, found = outer_value, True
                break

            if trace == keys[:len(trace)] and isinstance(outer_value, Mapping):  # Recursion cutoff.
                value, found = self.get(
                    data=outer_value,
                    keys=keys,
                    path=trace
                )

        return value, found

    def set(self, keys: [object], value: object, **kwargs) -> bool:
        """
        Set dictionary item value based on nested keys.

        Parameters
        ----------
        keys: [object]
            Nested keys to set item value based on.
        value: object
            Item value.

        Returns
        -------
        updated: bool
            Whether the target item was updated.
        """
        data = kwargs.get('data', self.data)
        path = kwargs.get('path', [])
        updated = False

        # Looking for item location on dictionary:
        for outer_key, outer_value in data.items():
            trace = path + [outer_key]

            # Setting item value on dictionary:
            if trace == keys:
                data[outer_key] = value
                updated = True
                break

            if trace == keys[:len(trace)] and isinstance(outer_value, Mapping):  # Recursion cutoff.
                updated = self.set(
                    data=outer_value,
                    keys=keys,
                    value=value,
                    path=trace
                )

        return updated

    def add(self, keys: [object], value: object, **kwargs) -> bool:
        """
        Add dictionary item value based on nested keys.

        Parameters
        ----------
        keys: [object]
            Nested keys to add item based on.
        value: object
            Item value.

        Returns
        -------
        added: bool
            Whether the target item was added.
        """
        data = kwargs.get('data', self.data)
        added = False

        # Adding item on dictionary:
        if keys[0] not in data:
            if len(keys) == 1:
                data[keys[0]] = value
                added = True
            else:
                data[keys[0]] = {}

        # Looking for item location on dictionary:
        for outer_key, outer_value in data.items():
            if outer_key == keys[0]:  # Recursion cutoff.
                if len(keys) > 1 and isinstance(outer_value, Mapping):
                    added = self.add(
                        data=outer_value,
                        keys=keys[1:],
                        value=value
                    )

        return added

    def remove(self, keys: [object], **kwargs) -> bool:
        """
        Remove dictionary item based on nested keys.

        Parameters
        ----------
        keys: [object]
            Nested keys to remove item based on.

        Returns
        -------
        removed: bool
            Whether the target item was removed.
        """
        data = kwargs.get('data', self.data)
        path = kwargs.get('path', [])
        removed = False

        # Looking for item location on dictionary:
        for outer_key, outer_value in data.items():
            trace = path + [outer_key]

            # Removing item from dictionary:
            if trace == keys:
                del data[outer_key]
                removed = True
                break

            if trace == keys[:len(trace)] and isinstance(outer_value, Mapping):  # Recursion cutoff.
                removed = self.remove(
                    data=outer_value,
                    keys=keys,
                    path=trace
                )

        return removed

    def items(self, **kwargs) -> Iterator[object, object]:
        """
        Get dictionary items based on nested keys.

        Returns
        -------
        keys, value: Iterator[object, object]
            List of nested keys and list of values.
        """
        data = kwargs.get('data', self.data)
        path = kwargs.get('path', [])

        for outer_key, outer_value in data.items():
            if isinstance(outer_value, Mapping):
                for inner_key, inner_value in self.items(data=outer_value, path=path + [outer_key]):
                    yield inner_key, inner_value
            else:
                yield path + [outer_key], outer_value

    @staticmethod
    def merge(dict_list: [dict], overwrite: bool = False, concat: bool = False, default_value: object = None) -> dict:
        """
        Merges dictionaries, with value assignment based on order of occurrence. Overwrites values if and only if:
            - The key does not yet exist on merged dictionary;
            - The current value of the key on merged dictionary is the default value.

        Parameters
        ----------
        dict_list: [dict]
            List of dictionaries.
        overwrite: bool
            Overwrites occurrences of values. If false, keep the first occurrence of each value found.
        concat: bool
            Concatenates occurrences of values for the same key.
        default_value: object
            Default value used as a reference to override dictionary attributes.

        Returns
        -------
        md: dict
            Merged dictionary.
        """
        dict_list = [d for d in dict_list if d is not None and isinstance(d, dict)] if dict_list is not None else []
        assert len(dict_list), f"no dictionaries given."

        # Keeping the first occurrence of each value:
        if not overwrite:
            dict_list = [Dict(d) for d in dict_list]

            for i, d in enumerate(dict_list[:-1]):
                for keys, value in d.items():
                    if value != default_value:
                        for j, next_d in enumerate(dict_list[i+1:], start=i+1):
                            next_d.remove(keys=keys)

            dict_list = [d.data for d in dict_list]

        md = benedict()
        md.merge(*dict_list, overwrite=True, concat=concat)

        return md
```

Definition of the `main` method to show examples.

```
import json


def main() -> None:
    dict_list = [
        {1: 'a', 2: None, 3: {4: None, 5: {6: None}}},
        {1: None, 2: None, 3: {4: 'c', 5: {6: {7: None}}}},
        {1: None, 2: 'b', 3: {4: None, 5: {6: {7: 'd'}}}},
        {1: None, 2: 'b', 3: {4: None, 5: {6: {8: {9: {10: ['e', 'f']}}}}}},
        {1: None, 2: 'b', 3: {4: None, 5: {6: {8: {9: {10: ['g', 'h']}}}}}},
    ]

    d = Dict(data=dict_list[-1])

    print("Dictionary operations test:\n")
    print(f"data = {json.dumps(d.data, indent=4)}\n")
    print(f"d = Dict(data=data)")

    keys = [11]
    value = {12: {13: 14}}
    print(f"d.get(keys={keys}) --> {d.get(keys=keys)}")
    print(f"d.set(keys={keys}, value={value}) --> {d.set(keys=keys, value=value)}")
    print(f"d.add(keys={keys}, value={value}) --> {d.add(keys=keys, value=value)}")
    keys = [11, 12, 13]
    value = 14
    print(f"d.add(keys={keys}, value={value}) --> {d.add(keys=keys, value=value)}")
    value = 15
    print(f"d.set(keys={keys}, value={value}) --> {d.set(keys=keys, value=value)}")
    keys = [11]
    print(f"d.get(keys={keys}) --> {d.get(keys=keys)}")
    keys = [11, 12]
    print(f"d.get(keys={keys}) --> {d.get(keys=keys)}")
    keys = [11, 12, 13]
    print(f"d.get(keys={keys}) --> {d.get(keys=keys)}")
    keys = [11, 12, 13, 15]
    print(f"d.get(keys={keys}) --> {d.get(keys=keys)}")
    keys = [2]
    print(f"d.remove(keys={keys}) --> {d.remove(keys=keys)}")
    print(f"d.remove(keys={keys}) --> {d.remove(keys=keys)}")
    print(f"d.get(keys={keys}) --> {d.get(keys=keys)}")

    print("\n-----------------------------\n")
    print("Dictionary values match test:\n")
    print(f"data = {json.dumps(d.data, indent=4)}\n")
    print(f"d = Dict(data=data)")

    for keys, value in d.items():
        real_value, found = d.get(keys=keys)
        status = "found" if found else "not found"
        print(f"d{keys} = {value} == {real_value} ({status}) --> {value == real_value}")

    print("\n-----------------------------\n")
    print("Dictionaries merge test:\n")

    for i, d in enumerate(dict_list, start=1):
        print(f"d{i} = {d}")

    dict_list_ = [f"d{i}" for i, d in enumerate(dict_list, start=1)]
    print(f"dict_list = [{', '.join(dict_list_)}]")

    md = Dict.merge(dict_list=dict_list)
    print("\nmd = Dict.merge(dict_list=dict_list)")
    print("print(md)")
    print(f"{json.dumps(md, indent=4)}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### Output

```
Dictionary operations test:

data = {
    "1": null,
    "2": "b",
    "3": {
        "4": null,
        "5": {
            "6": {
                "8": {
                    "9": {
                        "10": [
                            "g",
                            "h"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

d = Dict(data=data)
d.get(keys=[11]) --> (None, False)
d.set(keys=[11], value={12: {13: 14}}) --> False
d.add(keys=[11], value={12: {13: 14}}) --> True
d.add(keys=[11, 12, 13], value=14) --> False
d.set(keys=[11, 12, 13], value=15) --> True
d.get(keys=[11]) --> ({12: {13: 15}}, True)
d.get(keys=[11, 12]) --> ({13: 15}, True)
d.get(keys=[11, 12, 13]) --> (15, True)
d.get(keys=[11, 12, 13, 15]) --> (None, False)
d.remove(keys=[2]) --> True
d.remove(keys=[2]) --> False
d.get(keys=[2]) --> (None, False)

-----------------------------

Dictionary values match test:

data = {
    "1": null,
    "3": {
        "4": null,
        "5": {
            "6": {
                "8": {
                    "9": {
                        "10": [
                            "g",
                            "h"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "11": {
        "12": {
            "13": 15
        }
    }
}

d = Dict(data=data)
d[1] = None == None (found) --> True
d[3, 4] = None == None (found) --> True
d[3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10] = ['g', 'h'] == ['g', 'h'] (found) --> True
d[11, 12, 13] = 15 == 15 (found) --> True

-----------------------------

Dictionaries merge test:

d1 = {1: 'a', 2: None, 3: {4: None, 5: {6: None}}}
d2 = {1: None, 2: None, 3: {4: 'c', 5: {6: {7: None}}}}
d3 = {1: None, 2: 'b', 3: {4: None, 5: {6: {7: 'd'}}}}
d4 = {1: None, 2: 'b', 3: {4: None, 5: {6: {8: {9: {10: ['e', 'f']}}}}}}
d5 = {1: None, 2: 'b', 3: {4: None, 5: {6: {8: {9: {10: ['g', 'h']}}}}}}
dict_list = [d1, d2, d3, d4, d5]

md = Dict.merge(dict_list=dict_list)
print(md)
{
    "1": "a",
    "2": "b",
    "3": {
        "4": "c",
        "5": {
            "6": {
                "7": "d",
                "8": {
                    "9": {
                        "10": [
                            "e",
                            "f"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```