# Dictionaries and default values

Tags: python, dictionary, coding-style

Assuming `connectionDetails` is a Python dictionary, what's the best, most elegant, most "pythonic" way of refactoring code like this?

```
if "host" in connectionDetails:
    host = connectionDetails["host"]
else:
    host = someDefaultValue
```

Answer (score 456, accepted):

Like this:

```
host = connectionDetails.get('host', someDefaultValue)
```

Comment: Note that the second argument is a value, not a key.

Comment: The if/else example is looking up the key in the dictionary twice, while the default example might only be doing one lookup. Besides dictionary lookups potentially being costly in more extreme cases (where you probably shouldn't use Python to begin with), dictionary lookups are function calls too. But I am seeing that the if/else takes about 1/3 less time with my test using string keys and int values in Python 3.4, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: One gotcha I found here is that there is a difference between a missing key, which will return the default value, or a key present with the value set to `None` which will not get defaulted. To handle those sorts of values you can do: `host = connectionDetails.get('host')` and then `host = host if host is not None else someDefaultValue`

Answer (score 143):

You can also use the [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) like so:

```
from collections import defaultdict
a = defaultdict(lambda: "default", key="some_value")
a["blabla"] => "default"
a["key"] => "some_value"
```

You can pass any ordinary function instead of lambda:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def a():
  return 4

b = defaultdict(a, key="some_value")
b['absent'] => 4
b['key'] => "some_value"
```

Answer (score 33):

While `.get()` is a nice idiom, it's slower than `if/else` (and slower than `try/except` if presence of the key in the dictionary can be expected most of the time):

```
>>> timeit.timeit(setup="d={1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:0}", 
... stmt="try:\n a=d[1]\nexcept KeyError:\n a=10")
0.07691968797894333
>>> timeit.timeit(setup="d={1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:0}", 
... stmt="try:\n a=d[2]\nexcept KeyError:\n a=10")
0.4583777282275605
>>> timeit.timeit(setup="d={1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:0}", 
... stmt="a=d.get(1, 10)")
0.17784020746671558
>>> timeit.timeit(setup="d={1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:0}", 
... stmt="a=d.get(2, 10)")
0.17952161730158878
>>> timeit.timeit(setup="d={1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:0}", 
... stmt="if 1 in d:\n a=d[1]\nelse:\n a=10")
0.10071221458065338
>>> timeit.timeit(setup="d={1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:0}", 
... stmt="if 2 in d:\n a=d[2]\nelse:\n a=10")
0.06966537335119938
```

Comment: I still don't see _why_ `if/then` would be faster. Both cases require a dictionary lookup, and unless the invocation of `get()` is _so_ much slower, what else accounts for the slowdown?

Comment: @Jens: Function calls are expensive.

Comment: Which shouldn't be a big deal in a heavily populated dictionary, correct? Meaning the function call is not going to matter much if the actual lookup is costly. It probably only matters in toy examples.

Comment: @zehelvion: Dictionary lookup is `O(1)` regardless of dictionary size, so the function call overhead is relevant.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Isn't O(1) an idealization that assumes no collisions? Is this a safe assumption for large dictionaries?

Comment: @irh: Yes, it assumes no collisions. The [amortized worst case](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) is `O(n)`, but in practice it's rather difficult to construct a dictionary with hash collisions.

Comment: it is bizarre if the overhead of calling a function would make you decide against using get. Use what your fellow team members can read best.

Comment: Great analysis Tim, it looks like ternary if versions (`a=d[1] if 1 in d else 10` and `a=d[2] if 2 in d else 10`) have the same performance characteristics as the traditional if statement, with Python 3.5.1 at least.

Comment: You can improve the speed of the `.get` method a little by caching it, but `.get` is also slow because it catches the `KeyError`; I presume it does that at the C level, but it's still slower than `if...else` if the `KeyError` is likely to be raised more than 10% of the time. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35451912/4014959) for some `timeit` comparisons between `in` and `.get`.

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer "premature optimisation" syndrome :) It is good to know the relative performance of different forms to put in for when profiling shows an issue, along with a comment as to why get() isn't used so someone doesn't go replacing with a get() in the future. But otherwise, the easy to understand form should absolutely trump other considerations.

Comment: Please avoid pre-mature optimization, get vs. if/else is likely immaterial to the overall performance of what most people are doing. Evaluate your performance by profiling your implementation in your environment in the soup of the rest of your or your team's decisions...

Answer (score 22):

For multiple different defaults try this:

```
connectionDetails = { "host": "www.example.com" }
defaults = { "host": "127.0.0.1", "port": 8080 }

completeDetails = {}
completeDetails.update(defaults)
completeDetails.update(connectionDetails)
completeDetails["host"]  # ==> "www.example.com"
completeDetails["port"]  # ==> 8080
```

Comment: This is a good idiomatic solution, but there is a pitfall. Unexpected outcomes may result if connectionDetails is supplied with `None` or the emptyString as one of the values in the key-value pairs. The `defaults` dictionary could potentially have one of its values unintentionally blanked out. (see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354436)

Answer (score 18):

This is not exactly the question asked for but there is a method in python dictionaries: `dict.setdefault`

```py
    host = connectionDetails.setdefault('host',someDefaultValue)
```

However this method sets the value of `connectionDetails['host']` to `someDefaultValue` if key `host` is not already defined, unlike what the question asked.

Comment: Note that `setdefault()` returns value, so this works as well:
`host = connectionDetails.setdefault('host', someDefaultValue)`. Just beware that it will set `connectionDetails['host']` to default value if the key wasn't there before.

Answer (score 11):

(this is a late answer)

An alternative is to subclass the `dict` class and implement the [`__missing__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__missing__#object.__missing__) method, like this:

```
class ConnectionDetails(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        if key == 'host':
            return "localhost"
        raise KeyError(key)
```

Examples:

```
>>> connection_details = ConnectionDetails(port=80)

>>> connection_details['host']
'localhost'

>>> connection_details['port']
80

>>> connection_details['password']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
  File "python", line 6, in __missing__
KeyError: 'password'
```

Comment: This is the most obvious method for me but its still a little clumsy when defining the dictionary as you can no longer use dictionary constructors

Answer (score 7):

You can use `dict.get()` for default values.

```
d = {"a" :1, "b" :2}
x = d.get("a",5)
y = d.get("c",6)

# This will give
# x = 1, y = 6
# as the result
```

Since "a" is in the keys, `x = d.get("a",5)` will return associated value `1`. Since "c" is not in the keys, `y = d.get("c",6)` will return the default value `6`.

Answer (score 5):

Testing @Tim Pietzcker's suspicion about the situation in PyPy (5.2.0-alpha0) for Python 3.3.5, I find that indeed both `.get()` and the `if`/`else` way perform similar. Actually it seems that in the if/else case there is even only a single lookup if the condition and the assignment involve the same key (compare with the last case where there is two lookups).

```
>>>> timeit.timeit(setup="d={1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:0}",
.... stmt="try:\n a=d[1]\nexcept KeyError:\n a=10")
0.011889292989508249
>>>> timeit.timeit(setup="d={1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:0}",
.... stmt="try:\n a=d[2]\nexcept KeyError:\n a=10")
0.07310474599944428
>>>> timeit.timeit(setup="d={1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:0}",
.... stmt="a=d.get(1, 10)")
0.010391917996457778
>>>> timeit.timeit(setup="d={1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:0}",
.... stmt="a=d.get(2, 10)")
0.009348208011942916
>>>> timeit.timeit(setup="d={1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:0}",
.... stmt="if 1 in d:\n a=d[1]\nelse:\n a=10")
0.011475925013655797
>>>> timeit.timeit(setup="d={1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:0}",
.... stmt="if 2 in d:\n a=d[2]\nelse:\n a=10")
0.009605801998986863
>>>> timeit.timeit(setup="d={1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:0}",
.... stmt="if 2 in d:\n a=d[2]\nelse:\n a=d[1]")
0.017342638995614834
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lamba function for this as a one-liner. Make a new object     `connectionDetails2` which is accessed like a function...

```
connectionDetails2 = lambda k: connectionDetails[k] if k in connectionDetails.keys() else "DEFAULT"
```

Now use

```
connectionDetails2(k)
```

instead of

```
connectionDetails[k]
```

which returns the dictionary value if `k` is in the keys, otherwise it returns `"DEFAULT"`

Comment: I upvoted you but the problem with your solution is that dicts work with [] but lambdas work with()

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that all these answers are ok but it shows that there is no 'nice' way of doing this. I use dictionaries instead of case statements all the time and to add a default clause I just call the following function:

```
def choose(choise, choises, default):
    """Choose a choice from the choises given
    """
    return choises[choise] if choise in choises else default
```

That way I can use normal dictionaries without special default clauses etc.