# Python not in dict condition sentence performance

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

Does anybody know about what is better to use thinking about speed and resources? Link to some trusted sources would be much appreciated.

```
if key not in dictionary.keys():
```

or

```
if not dictionary.get(key):
```

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, you'd do

```
if key not in dictionary:
```

since dicts are iterated over by keys.

Secondly, the two statements are not equivalent - the second condition would be true if the corresponding values is falsy (`0`, `""`, `[]` etc.), not only if the key doesn't exist.

Lastly, the first method is definitely faster and more pythonic. Function/method calls are expensive. If you're unsure, `timeit`.

Comment: Ok, 2nd is more pythonic but can't be used in situation when your dict can contain zeros, emptry strings or empty lists, right?

Comment: The first is more pythonic (if all you're trying to do is determine whether a dict has a given key). The second part of your comment is correct. Of course, all this depends on what you're actually trying to do - even a `try/except` block might be the best way to achieve that.

Comment: Hmm. In which situation `try/except` might be the best way?

Comment: For example if you plan on doing something with the value for the key, and you're 99% sure that there will be such a key. In this case, it's [easier to ask forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp).

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, using `in` is faster than using `get`, although the speed of `get` can be improved by caching the `get` method so it doesn't have to be looked up each time. Here are some `timeit` tests:

```
''' in vs get speed test

    Comparing the speed of cache retrieval / update using `get` vs using `in`

    http://stackoverflow.com/a/35451912/4014959

    Written by PM 2Ring 2015.12.01
    Updated for Python 3 2017.08.08
'''

from __future__ import print_function
from timeit import Timer
from random import randint
import dis

cache = {}

def get_cache(x):
    ''' retrieve / update cache using `get` '''
    res = cache.get(x)
    if res is None:
        res = cache[x] = x
    return res

def get_cache_defarg(x, get=cache.get):
    ''' retrieve / update cache using defarg `get` '''
    res = get(x)
    if res is None:
        res = cache[x] = x
    return res

def in_cache(x):
    ''' retrieve / update cache using `in` '''
    if x in cache:
        return cache[x]
    else:
        res = cache[x] = x
        return res

#slow to fast.
funcs = (
    get_cache, 
    get_cache_defarg,
    in_cache, 
)

def show_bytecode():
    for func in funcs:
        fname = func.__name__
        print('\n%s' % fname)
        dis.dis(func)

def time_test(reps, loops):
    ''' Print timing stats for all the functions '''
    for func in funcs:
        fname = func.__name__
        print('\n%s: %s' % (fname, func.__doc__))
        setup = 'from __main__ import data, ' + fname
        cmd = 'for v in data: %s(v)' % (fname,)
        times = []
        t = Timer(cmd, setup)
        for i in range(reps):
            r = 0
            for j in range(loops):
                r += t.timeit(1)
                cache.clear()
            times.append(r)
        times.sort()
        print(times)

datasize = 1024
maxdata = 32
data = [randint(1, maxdata) for i in range(datasize)]

#show_bytecode()
time_test(3, 500)
```

**typical output** on my 2Ghz machine running Python 2.6.6:

```
get_cache:  retrieve / update cache using `get` 
[0.65624237060546875, 0.68499755859375, 0.76354193687438965]

get_cache_defarg:  retrieve / update cache using defarg `get` 
[0.54204297065734863, 0.55032730102539062, 0.56702113151550293]

in_cache:  retrieve / update cache using `in` 
[0.48754477500915527, 0.49125504493713379, 0.50087881088256836]
```

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Use `if key not in dictionary`. This is idiomatic, robust and fast.

---

There are four versions of relevance to this question: the 2 posed in the question, and the optimal variant of them:

```
key not in dictionary.keys()  # inA
key not in dictionary         # inB
not dictionary.get(key)       # getA
sentinel = object()
dictionary.get(key, sentinel) is not sentinel  # getB
```

Both `A` variants have shortcomings that mean you should not use them. `inA` needlessly creates a dict view on the keys - this adds an indirection step. `getA` looks at the truth *of the value* - this leads to incorrect results for values such as `''` or `0`.

As for using `inB` over `getB`: both do the same thing, namely looking at whether there is a value for `key`. However, `getB` *also* returns that value or default and has to compare it against the sentinel. Consequently, using `get` is considerably slower:

```
$ PREPARE="
> import random
> data = {a: True for a in range(0, 512, 2)}
> sentinel=object()"
$ python3 -m perf timeit -s "$PREPARE" '27 in data'
.....................
Mean +- std dev: 33.9 ns +- 0.8 ns
$ python3 -m perf timeit -s "$PREPARE" 'data.get(27, sentinel) is not sentinel'
.....................
Mean +- std dev: 105 ns +- 5 ns
```

Note that `pypy3` has practically the same performance for both variants once the JIT has warmed up.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, I've tested it on python 3.4.3 and all three ways give the same result around 0.00001 second.

```
import random
a = {}
for i in range(0, 1000000):
        a[str(random.random())] = random.random()
import time
t1 = time.time(); 1 in a.keys(); t2 = time.time(); print("Time=%s" % (t2 - t1))
t1 = time.time(); 1 in a; t2 = time.time(); print("Time=%s" % (t2 - t1))
t1 = time.time(); not a.get(1); t2 = time.time(); print("Time=%s" % (t2 - t1))
```

Comment: This is not how you do performance testing. Use the [`timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html).

Comment: Also, all your tests will always return False because there can never be a `a[1]`.

Comment: use `xrange()` for iteration