# Which is faster a dictionary retrieve or a list indexing?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, profiling

I'm trying to decide which data structure best fits my needs.

Technical details apart, I may translate the needs of my program to use dictionaries or to use lists, and since performance will be an issue I was wondering what may be a faster solution. I ended up concluding that retrieving/indexing will be the critical operation.

So what's more efficient in terms of memory usage and speed?

Comment: Do you need to search the dict or list for the data, or can you just supply the necessary key or index? If you don't need to search, use a list. It's faster, and uses less RAM than a dict.

Comment: I'll supply the key or index. Curious that some other answer here states quite the contrary to this

Comment: For small collections (<100 items) the speed differences are minimal. But for large collections the dict will be around 20% slower. And it will certainly use more RAM. On 32 bit Python `list(range(1000))` consumes 4556 bytes; that doesn't include the RAM needed to hold the integer objects themselves. In contrast, a dict holding the same data consumes 24624 bytes.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't need to search, use a list. It's faster, and uses less RAM than a dict. For small collections (<100 items) the speed differences are minimal, but for large collections the dict will be around 20% slower. And it will certainly use more RAM.

Here's some `timeit` code that compares the access speed of list vs dict. It also shows the RAM consumed by the collection objects themselves (but not that of the data objects they hold).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

''' Compare list vs dict access speed 

    See http://stackoverflow.com/q/39192442/4014959

    Written by PM 2Ring 2016.08.29
'''

from sys import getsizeof
from timeit import Timer

commands = {'dict' : 'for i in r:d[i]', 'list' : 'for i in r:a[i]'}

def time_test(loops, reps):
    timings = []
    setup = 'from __main__ import r, a, d'
    for name, cmd in commands.items():
        result = Timer(cmd, setup).repeat(reps, loops)
        result.sort()
        timings.append((result, name))

    timings.sort()
    for result, name in timings:
        print(name, result)

    #Find the ratio of slowest / fastest
    tlo, thi = [timings[i][0][0] for i in (0, -1)]
    print('ratio: {0:f}\n'.format(thi / tlo))

num = 2000
r = range(num)
a = list(r)
d = {i:i for i in r}

fmt = 'Sizes: num={}, list={}, dict={}'
print(fmt.format(num, getsizeof(a), getsizeof(d)))

loops, reps = 2000, 3
time_test(loops, reps)
```

**output**

```
Sizes: num=2000, list=9056, dict=49200
list [1.2624831110006198, 1.3356713940011105, 1.406396518003021]
dict [1.506095960001403, 1.525646976999269, 1.5623748449979757]
ratio: 1.192963
```

The speed difference is actually higher than it appears in those results, since the time taken to retrieve the integers from the `r` range object is roughly the same as the time taken to do the list & dict accesses. You can measure that by adding an entry like this to the `commands` dictionary:

```
'none': 'for i in r:i'
```

Answer (score 1):

https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity provides all the info you're looking for

Comment: Nice suggestion! Somebody -1 it but I got to upvote it for a 0 at least

Answer (score 0):

Well, retrieving from a dict has the same complexity as retrieving from a list:

```
_dict[1]
_list[1]
```

but..., with dicts, u can use:

```
_dict.get(1, 'something else')
```

It just returns 'something else' if there is no key `1`. Using lists, you cannot do that. You just want to get item indexed by number `1`. If you will ask for item outside your list, so index will be higher than your list length, then your program will raise `IndexError` which must be handled. Next problem will be that you will have to know size of that list, so you need to check it first.

Comment: FWIW, using `dict.get` is ok if the key does actually exist most of the time, but it works internally by catching the KeyError exception. Python exceptions are very fast when the exception isn't raised, but they slow right down when the exception occurs. If you expect that the key won't exist more than 5 or 10% of the time it's faster to use an explicit `in` test than to use `.get`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35451912/4014959) for some timing info.