# Loop alternatives to if else blocks

Tags: python

I'm trying to make some code that I wrote hastily with a lot of copy/pastes a little cleaner.  I noticed that I have two functions that are irritatingly close to doing the same thing.  Here's the gists of them:

```
def determine_risk(difference):
    if difference > ON_TRACK:
        return 'On Track'
    elif difference < HIGH_RISK:
        return 'High Risk'
    else:
        return 'Low Risk'

def determine_completeness(pct_complete):
    if pct_complete == UNSTARTED:
        return 'Unstarted'
    elif pct_complete > READY:
        return 'Ready'
    else:
        return 'In Process'
```

I'd love to turn this into one function.  Something like

```
def determine_condition(metric, [list_of_conditions], [list_of_outcomes], fallback)
    for condition, outcome in zip(list_of_conditions, list_of_outomes):
         if metric satisfies condition:
              return outcome
    return fallback
```

The problem is I don't think it's possible to store conditional checks in a list like that!  Posting here in case someone can show me a way, or sees an alternative approach to combining these similar types of function into one

Comment: You mean [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47728364/python-design-pattern-for-many-conditions)?

Comment: wrap your codition in functions, use those functions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store conditions as an array of lambda expressions, e.g.:

```
a = lambda x: x > 1
b = lambda x: x < 5
conditions = [a, b]
```

But to be honest, I wouldn't.  There's absolutely nothing wrong with the two functions in your first example - they have sensible names, and I can clearly tell when reading them what they do.

If you refactored your code to use the second example, you lose this.  Whenever I see a call to `determine_condition`, I have to go and read what the function does, and figure out that it's just a generic way of checking a bunch of conditions.

Sometimes it's better to sacrifice brevity at the altar of readability, and for me this is one of those times.

**Edit**

The lambda examples I gave didn't return booleans which is what you'd need - modified so they do

Comment: Don't use a lambda expression as a one-line `def` statement.

Comment: @chepner that's the simplest example I could think of to demonstrate how the OP might achieve what he was trying to do.  My overall point is that I don't think you should do things like this :)

Comment: I consider this a great answer. "Here's how you can do what you're trying to do, but here's why you shouldn't do that at all" is a pretty common pattern for SO answers, and I don't mind there being some code that might get flagged in review in the block of "This works, but don't do it" code.

Comment: I agree.  Learning about philosophy of writing good code is as welcome as neat tricks to streamline code. Thank you @RobGwynn-Jones