# default value for missing value for a key in json in http output

Tags: python, json

I have situation where i get http response with missing value for a key.

```
import requests
http = requests.get(url, verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(self.username, self.password),
                                    timeout=self.timeout, headers=headers)
```

**http.text** gives output but **http.json** doesn't give any output.I understand that this issue is because of Invalid json format.

```
'{"PLMNID":[                 
               {  
                  "mNc":,
                  "id":3,
                  "mcc":
               },
               {  
                  "mNc":,
                  "id":4,
                  "mcc":
               },
               {  
                  "mNc":,
                  "id":5,
                  "mcc":
               },
               {  
                  "mNc":,
                  "id":6,
                  "mcc":
               }}'
```

Currently I retrun http.json.I see no response and also no error.
Now i planning to return http.text output and some how add default value (may be '' or null)for missing key and proceed.

Do we have any python json api which will add default value for missing value for a key.

Comment: .get with defaults /  defaultdict ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491287/elegant-way-to-check-if-a-nested-key-exists-in-a-python-dict/43491315#43491315  , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358983/dictionaries-and-default-values

Comment: What's the response `Content-Type`?

Comment: This is invalid json, so the real solution is to contact the API maintainers and report the bug.

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
text = '{"sa": 1, "df":[{"vc":1,"mn":2},{"vc":1,"mn":}]}'
len_text = len(text)
j = 0
js = None

while j <= len_text:
    try:
        js = json.loads(text)
    except json.JSONDecodeError as mn :
        if mn.msg == "Expecting value":
            text1 = list(text)
            text1.insert(mn.pos, 'null')
            text = "".join(text1)
        else:
            print("Got other error than Expecting value at pos:{0} with error:{1}".format(mn.pos, mn.msg))
            break
    j += 1

print(js)
```

This code is checking for JSON decode error and when "Expecting value" msg appears it fills with "null" value at the index of JSON text. This repeated until it fills the "null" value or breaks if some other error msg appears.

Comment: Relying on the exception's message is brittle at best. Then, the `else` block should actually re-raise the original exception (so you have the full error message AND traceback) instead of printing it. And finally, you should use a `while` loop here. Oh and yes: in python2, this would raise a ValueError, not a json.JSONDecodeError, and the error message is different...

Comment: I tried this but JSONDecodeError  is not supported in 2.7.6 ?