# Python initialize empty dictionary with default values type

Tags: python, dictionary, types

I want to use a dictionary with string as **key** and set() as **values**.

How do I initialize an empty dictionary with a specific type as values?

I need it because I don't want to check everytime if the key is already in the dictionary and put an if to create the set instead of just using .add()

is it possible?

Comment: You appear to be looking for [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdictt)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dictionaries and default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358983/dictionaries-and-default-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
mydict = defaultdict(set)
mydict["key"].add(5)
```

Comment: Is it also possible to use just `dict`? i.e. `mydict = dict(set)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `setdefault()` function on standard python `dict` to initialize keys not present.

setdefault() :

- returns default value passed if key is not present.
- returns None if key is not present and no default value passed
- returns value of key if key is present.

```
    x=dict()

    x.setdefault('a',set()).add(5)

    print(x) #{'a': {5}}

    x.setdefault('a',set()).add(6)

    print(x) #{'a': {5, 6}}
```