# Discord.py different variables for each guild

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a verification bot and would like users to be able to set a custom role. Currently the role that is given to people when they verify is Member but some guilds might want to use a different role name. Is this possible to do?

I can change the source code but that will change the role name for every server I want each server to be able to set the role on their own

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

create a dictionary, where the guild id would be a key, and the value would be the role they want to assign after verification.

When a user gets verified, you check the dictionary for a role the bot should assign.

[dictionaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

[Default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358983/dictionaries-and-default-values)