# Efficient way to remove keys with empty strings from a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict and would like to remove all the keys for which there are empty value strings.

```
metadata = {u'Composite:PreviewImage': u'(Binary data 101973 bytes)',
            u'EXIF:CFAPattern2': u''}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 271, accepted):

Python 2.X

```
dict((k, v) for k, v in metadata.iteritems() if v)
```

---

Python 2.7 - 3.X

```
{k: v for k, v in metadata.items() if v}
```

Note that all of your keys have values.  It's just that some of those values are the empty string.  There's no such thing as a key in a dict without a value; if it didn't have a value, it wouldn't be in the dict.

Comment: +1.  It's important to note that this does not actually remove the keys from an existing dictionary.  Rather, it creates a new dictionary.  Usually this is exactly what someone wants and is probably what the OP needs, but it is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: This also kills v=0, which is fine, if that is what is wanted.

Comment: This also rids v=False, which isn't _exactly_ what OP asked.

Comment: its `.item()` for python3

Comment: @shredding: You mean `.items()`.

Comment: For later versions of python you should also use the dictionary generator: `{k: v for k, v in metadata.items() if v is not None}`

Comment: The value in a python dict can be None, which essentially describes exactly the case of a key in a dict without a value.

Comment: @AirsourceLtd: No, it does not.  It describes the case of a key whose value is None.  In the same way, `[]` is a list that does not contain any value, which is different from `[None]`, which is a list containing the value `None`.

Comment: I think for python3 the best is: `{k: v for k, v in metadata.items() if v}`

Comment: @ArdiNusawan thanks, this actually works for empty strings, unlike the given answer (3.8.3)

Comment: "v is not None" doesn't remove the empty strings (e.g. '')

Answer (score 85):

It can get even shorter than [BrenBarn's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118700/1641609) (and more readable I think)

```
{k: v for k, v in metadata.items() if v}
```

Tested with Python 2.7.3.

Comment: This also kills zero values.

Comment: To preserve 0 (zero) you can use `... if v!=None` like so:  `{k: v for k, v in metadata.items() if v!=None}`

Comment: {k: v for k, v in metadata.items() if v!=None}  doesn't get rid of empty strings.

Comment: dictionary comprehensions is supported only with Python 2.7+ for compatibility with prior versions please use @BrenBarn's solution.

Comment: Should always compare None with, 'is not', instead of '!='. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14247419/2368836

Comment: This solution will not work for `bool` attribute if it will be `false`.

Comment: works on Python 3.9 too. Works when v is False. Works when v is '' (empty string).

Comment: Note: for those wondering about the PO request to remove items from dict, you can't remove a key from a dict in-place without copying the dict. You will get a runtime error for changing the size of dict during iteration

Answer (score 24):

If you really need to modify the original dictionary:

```
empty_keys = [k for k,v in metadata.iteritems() if not v]
for k in empty_keys:
    del metadata[k]
```

Note that we have to make a list of the empty keys because we can't modify a dictionary while iterating through it (as you may have noticed). This is less expensive (memory-wise) than creating a brand-new dictionary, though, unless there are a lot of entries with empty values.

Comment: this will also remove value 0 and 0 is not empty

Comment: If you are using Python 3+ you have to replace `.iteritems()` with `.items()`, the first doesn't work anymore in latest Python versions.

Answer (score 22):

If you want a full-featured, yet succinct approach to handling real-world data structures which are often nested, and can even contain cycles, I recommend looking at [the remap utility from the boltons utility package](http://boltons.readthedocs.org/en/latest/iterutils.html#nested).

After `pip install boltons` or copying [iterutils.py](https://github.com/mahmoud/boltons/blob/master/boltons/iterutils.py) into your project, just do:

```
from boltons.iterutils import remap

drop_falsey = lambda path, key, value: bool(value)
clean = remap(metadata, visit=drop_falsey)
```

[This page](http://sedimental.org/remap.html) has many more examples, including ones working with much larger objects from Github's API.

It's pure-Python, so it works everywhere, and is fully tested in Python 2.7 and 3.3+. Best of all, I wrote it for exactly cases like this, so if you find a case it doesn't handle, you can bug me to fix it [right here](https://github.com/mahmoud/boltons/issues).

Comment: This solution worked great for a similar problem i had: stripping empty values from deeply nested lists inside of dictionaries. Thanks!

Comment: This is good, as you are not reinventing the wheel, and providing a solution for nested objects. Thanks!

Comment: I really liked the article you wrote for your library, and this is a useful library!

Comment: Thank you for this. Not to repeat props but this cleanly handled nested values. Very nice!

Comment: This is an excellent answer, and it can go beyond this particular question. Though, if somebody found themselves trying to answer that question, they will probably come across similar questions that can be solved with this remap function.

Answer (score 16):

Based on [Ryan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24688773/394647), if you also have lists and nested dictionaries:

For Python 2:

```
def remove_empty_from_dict(d):
    if type(d) is dict:
        return dict((k, remove_empty_from_dict(v)) for k, v in d.iteritems() if v and remove_empty_from_dict(v))
    elif type(d) is list:
        return [remove_empty_from_dict(v) for v in d if v and remove_empty_from_dict(v)]
    else:
        return d
```

For Python 3:

```
def remove_empty_from_dict(d):
    if type(d) is dict:
        return dict((k, remove_empty_from_dict(v)) for k, v in d.items() if v and remove_empty_from_dict(v))
    elif type(d) is list:
        return [remove_empty_from_dict(v) for v in d if v and remove_empty_from_dict(v)]
    else:
        return d
```

Comment: Ha, nice extension! It is a good solution for dictionaries like the following: `d = { "things": [{ "name": "" }] }`

Answer (score 15):

[BrenBarn's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118700/1142167) is ideal (and pythonic, I might add). Here is another (fp) solution, however:

```
from operator import itemgetter
dict(filter(itemgetter(1), metadata.items()))
```

Answer (score 9):

If you have a nested dictionary, and you want this to work even for empty sub-elements, you can use a recursive variant of BrenBarn's suggestion:

```
def scrub_dict(d):
    if type(d) is dict:
        return dict((k, scrub_dict(v)) for k, v in d.iteritems() if v and scrub_dict(v))
    else:
        return d
```

Comment: Use `items()` instead of `iteritems()` for Python 3

Answer (score 7):

For python 3

```
dict((k, v) for k, v in metadata.items() if v)
```

Answer (score 6):

### Quick Answer (TL;DR)

#### Example01

```
### example01 -------------------

mydict  =   { "alpha":0,
              "bravo":"0",
              "charlie":"three",
              "delta":[],
              "echo":False,
              "foxy":"False",
              "golf":"",
              "hotel":"   ",                        
            }
newdict =   dict([(vkey, vdata) for vkey, vdata in mydict.iteritems() if(vdata) ])
print newdict

### result01 -------------------
result01 ='''
{'foxy': 'False', 'charlie': 'three', 'bravo': '0'}
'''
```

### Detailed Answer

#### Problem

- **Context:**  Python 2.x
- **Scenario:** Developer wishes modify a dictionary to exclude blank values

  - aka remove empty values from a dictionary
  - aka delete keys with blank values
  - aka filter dictionary for non-blank values over each key-value pair

#### Solution

- example01 use python list-comprehension syntax with simple conditional to remove "empty" values

#### Pitfalls

- example01 only operates on a copy of the original dictionary (does not modify in place)
- example01 may produce unexpected results depending on what developer means by "empty"

  - Does developer mean to keep values that are [falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9573259/42223)?
  - If the values in the dictionary are not gauranteed to be strings, developer may have unexpected data loss.
  - result01 shows that only three key-value pairs were preserved from the original set

#### Alternate example

- example02 helps deal with potential pitfalls
- The approach is to use a more precise definition of "empty" by changing the conditional.
- Here we only want to filter out values that evaluate to blank strings.
- Here we also use .strip() to filter out values that consist of only whitespace.

#### Example02

```
### example02 -------------------

mydict  =   { "alpha":0,
              "bravo":"0",
              "charlie":"three",
              "delta":[],
              "echo":False,
              "foxy":"False",
              "golf":"",
              "hotel":"   ",
            }
newdict =   dict([(vkey, vdata) for vkey, vdata in mydict.iteritems() if(str(vdata).strip()) ])
print newdict

### result02 -------------------
result02 ='''
{'alpha': 0,
  'bravo': '0', 
  'charlie': 'three', 
  'delta': [],
  'echo': False,
  'foxy': 'False'
  }
'''
```

#### See also

- [list-comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Python_syntax_and_semantics&oldid=684110148#List_comprehensions)
- [falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9573259/42223)
- [checking for empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573244/)
- [modifying original dictionary in place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118839/42223)
- [dictionary comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21482035/42223)
- [pitfalls of checking for empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9573278/42223)

Answer (score 5):

Building on the answers from [patriciasz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21482035/3381305) and [nneonneo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118839/3381305), and accounting for the possibility that you might want to delete keys that have only certain falsy things (e.g. `''`) but not others (e.g. `0`), or perhaps you even want to include some truthy things (e.g. `'SPAM'`), then you could make a highly specific hitlist:

```
unwanted = ['', u'', None, False, [], 'SPAM']
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't quite work, because for example `0 in unwanted` evaluates to `True`. We need to discriminate between `0` and other falsy things, so we have to use `is`:

```
any([0 is i for i in unwanted])
```

...evaluates to `False`.

Now use it to `del` the unwanted things:

```
unwanted_keys = [k for k, v in metadata.items() if any([v is i for i in unwanted])]
for k in unwanted_keys: del metadata[k]
```

If you want a new dictionary, instead of modifying `metadata` in place:

```
newdict = {k: v for k, v in metadata.items() if not any([v is i for i in unwanted])}
```

Comment: really  nice shot, it address many problems at once and it solves the question, thank you to make it clear

Comment: Cool! It works for this example. However, it doesn't work when an item in the dictionary is `[]`

Answer (score 2):

I read all replies in this thread and some referred also to this thread:
[Remove empty dicts in nested dictionary with recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529312/remove-empty-dicts-in-nested-dictionary-with-recursive-function)

I originally used solution here and it worked great:

**Attempt 1: Too Hot (not performant or future-proof)**:

```
def scrub_dict(d):
    if type(d) is dict:
        return dict((k, scrub_dict(v)) for k, v in d.iteritems() if v and scrub_dict(v))
    else:
        return d
```

But some performance and compatibility concerns were raised in Python 2.7 world:

1. use `isinstance` instead of `type`
2. unroll the list comp into `for` loop for efficiency
3. use python3 safe `items` instead of `iteritems`

**Attempt 2: Too Cold (Lacks Memoization)**:

```
def scrub_dict(d):
    new_dict = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v,dict):
            v = scrub_dict(v)
        if not v in (u'', None, {}):
            new_dict[k] = v
    return new_dict
```

DOH! This is not recursive and not at all memoizant.

**Attempt 3: Just Right (so far)**:

```
def scrub_dict(d):
    new_dict = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v,dict):
            v = scrub_dict(v)
        if not v in (u'', None, {}):
            new_dict[k] = v
    return new_dict
```

Comment: unless i am blind, it looks to me that attempt 2 and 3 are exactly the same...

Answer (score 2):

"As I also currently write a desktop application for my work with Python, I found in data-entry application when there is lots of entry and which some are not mandatory thus user can left it blank, for validation purpose, it is easy to grab all entries and then discard empty key or value of a dictionary. So my code above a show how we can easy take them out, using dictionary comprehension and keep dictionary value element which is not blank. I use Python 3.8.3

```
data = {'':'', '20':'', '50':'', '100':'1.1', '200':'1.2'}

dic = {key:value for key,value in data.items() if value != ''}

print(dic)

{'100': '1.1', '200': '1.2'}
```

Comment: Please mention python version also will it support latest version ?

Comment: Your answer is currently flagged as low quality may be deleted. Please make sure your answer contains an explanation aside from any code.

Comment: @TimStack Please recommend deletion for LQ answers.

Comment: @10Rep I will not recommend deletion for an answer that may work as a solution but is merely lacking any descriptive comments. I would rather inform the user and teach them what a better answer looks like.

Comment: @HasseB Mir I use the latest Python 3.8.3

Comment: Hi @TimStack. My apology not giving any explanation, because I think the code is so simple. But I can understand your point, not giving any word or explanation can miss interpreted as rude or arrogant. I am sorry.

Answer (score 2):

To preserve 0 and False values but get rid of empty values you could use:

```
{k: v for k, v in metadata.items() if v or v == 0 or v is False}
```

For a nested dict with mixed types of values you could use:

```
def remove_empty_from_dict(d):
  if isinstance(d, dict):
    return dict((k, remove_empty_from_dict(v)) for k, v in d.items() \
            if v or v == 0 or v is False and remove_empty_from_dict(v) is not None)
  elif isinstance(d, list):
    return [remove_empty_from_dict(v) for v in d 
            if v or v == 0 or v is False and remove_empty_from_dict(v) is not None]
  else:
    if d or d == 0 or d is False:
      return d
```

Answer (score 1):

## Dicts mixed with Arrays

- The answer at **Attempt 3: Just Right (so far)** from [BlissRage's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49497994/433814) does not properly handle arrays elements. I'm including a patch in case anyone needs it. The method is handles list with the statement block of `if isinstance(v, list):`, which scrubs the list using the original `scrub_dict(d)` implementation.

```
    @staticmethod
    def scrub_dict(d):
        new_dict = {}
        for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                v = scrub_dict(v)
            if isinstance(v, list):
                v = scrub_list(v)
            if not v in (u'', None, {}, []):
                new_dict[k] = v
        return new_dict

    @staticmethod
    def scrub_list(d):
        scrubbed_list = []
        for i in d:
            if isinstance(i, dict):
                i = scrub_dict(i)
            scrubbed_list.append(i)
        return scrubbed_list
```

Comment: awesome . . . i had made this change in code base but missed your comment _/\_

Comment: This is a great answer but still left empty arrays, to fix change `if not v in (u'', None, {}, []):` to include an empty list

Comment: @SeanD, Just added your suggestion!!! Thank you for contributing to this!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way you can do this, is using dictionary comprehension. This should be compatible with `2.7+`

```
result = {
    key: value for key, value in
    {"foo": "bar", "lorem": None}.items()
    if value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option if you are using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

d = dict.fromkeys(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
d['b'] = 'not null'
d['c'] = ''  # empty string

print(d)

# convert `dict` to `Series` and replace any blank strings with `None`;
# use the `.dropna()` method and
# then convert back to a `dict`
d_ = pd.Series(d).replace('', None).dropna().to_dict()

print(d_)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of Methods mentioned above ignores if there are any integers and float with values 0 & 0.0

If someone wants to avoid the above can use below code(removes empty strings and None values from nested dictionary and nested list):

```
def remove_empty_from_dict(d):
    if type(d) is dict:
        _temp = {}
        for k,v in d.items():
            if v == None or v == "":
                pass
            elif type(v) is int or type(v) is float:
                _temp[k] = remove_empty_from_dict(v)
            elif (v or remove_empty_from_dict(v)):
                _temp[k] = remove_empty_from_dict(v)
        return _temp
    elif type(d) is list:
        return [remove_empty_from_dict(v) for v in d if( (str(v).strip() or str(remove_empty_from_dict(v)).strip()) and (v != None or remove_empty_from_dict(v) != None))]
    else:
        return d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
metadata ={'src':'1921','dest':'1337','email':'','movile':''}
ot = {k: v for k, v in metadata.items() if v != ''}
print(f"Final {ot}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have an option with `filter` method:

```py
filtered_metadata = dict( filter(lambda val: val[1] != u'', metadata.items()) )
```

Answer (score -2):

## Some benchmarking:

### 1. List comprehension recreate dict

```
In [7]: %%timeit dic = {str(i):i for i in xrange(10)}; dic['10'] = None; dic['5'] = None
   ...: dic = {k: v for k, v in dic.items() if v is not None} 
   1000000 loops, best of 7: 375 ns per loop
```

### 2. List comprehension recreate dict using dict()

```
In [8]: %%timeit dic = {str(i):i for i in xrange(10)}; dic['10'] = None; dic['5'] = None
   ...: dic = dict((k, v) for k, v in dic.items() if v is not None)
1000000 loops, best of 7: 681 ns per loop
```

### 3. Loop and delete key if v is None

```
In [10]: %%timeit dic = {str(i):i for i in xrange(10)}; dic['10'] = None; dic['5'] = None
    ...: for k, v in dic.items():
    ...:   if v is None:
    ...:     del dic[k]
    ...: 
10000000 loops, best of 7: 160 ns per loop
```

so loop and delete is the fastest at 160ns, list comprehension is half as slow at ~375ns and with a call to `dict()` is half as slow again ~680ns.

Wrapping 3 into a function brings it back down again to about 275ns. Also for me PyPy was about twice as fast as neet python.

Comment: Loop and delete may also throw a RunTimeError, since it is not valid to modify a dictionary while iterating a view. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html s4.10.1

Comment: ah man yeah ok in python 3 that is true but not in python 2.7 as items returns a list, so you have to call `list(dic.items())` in py 3.

Dict comprehension ftw then? del still seems faster for a low ratio of Null/empty values. I guess building that list is just as bad for memory consumption than just recreating the dict.