# Python None comparison: should I use "is" or ==?

Tags: python, comparison, nonetype

My editor warns me when I compare `my_var == None`, but no warning when I use `my_var is None`.

I did a test in the Python shell and determined both are valid syntax, but my editor seems to be saying that `my_var is None` is preferred.

Is this the case, and if so, why?

Comment: PEP 8 says somewhere that you should compare to singletons using `is` - http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations

Comment: That poster is talking about Python 3, and my question is about Python 2.x.  I am not sure if this is a big enough difference to warrant both remaining but I edited the question to include that just in case.

Comment: I don't think this question is really a duplicate. The other was about == vs is in general, this one is about None in particular.

Comment: I've downvoted every answer because none of them gives a convincing reason, nor does PEP8.  It says "Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or is not, never the equality operators." Are True and False "singletons like None"?  Apparently, so I guess I should say "if x is True"? Are ints between -5 and 256 "singletons like None"?  Apparently (see @doublefelix 's answer), so I guess I should say "if x is -5" but "if x == -6"?  This seems like nonsense; why on earth would I want to memorize any of this? As far as I can see, == works perfectly well for all of these.

Answer (score 355, accepted):

#### Summary:

Use `is` when you want to check against an object's *identity* (e.g. checking to see if `var` is `None`).  Use `==` when you want to check *equality* (e.g. Is `var` equal to `3`?).

#### Explanation:

You can have custom classes where `my_var == None` will return `True`

e.g:

```
class Negator(object):
    def __eq__(self,other):
        return not other

thing = Negator()
print thing == None    #True
print thing is None    #False
```

`is` checks for object *identity*.  There is only 1 object `None`, so when you do `my_var is None`, you're checking whether they actually are the same object (not just *equivalent* objects)

In other words, `==` is a check for equivalence (which is defined from object to object) whereas `is` checks for object identity:

```
lst = [1,2,3]
lst == lst[:]  # This is True since the lists are "equivalent"
lst is lst[:]  # This is False since they're actually different objects
```

Comment: Do you mean by overloading the == operator to always return True when compared to None?

Comment: When does `is None` differ from `== None`?

Comment: @Blender In the case mentioned. `__eq__` can be defined in any way, but the behavior of `is` can't be changed so easily.

Comment: Ah, that last example with lst made it very clear.  Thank you.

Comment: @LevLevitsky: One of the example uses of Mython was "extending the protocols so any operator can be overloaded, even `is`". After a comment on the lists, he changed that to, "… even `is` (but only if you're insane)."

Comment: +1, but it would be even better if this answer included the PEP 8 reference that the others do (as well as explaining why the decision behind PEP 8 makes sense, which it already does).

Comment: @abarnert -- I wasn't even aware that PEP 8 made a recommendation here.  The point is that they're different operators that do different things.  There might be cases where `object == None` actually *is* the correct idiom (though I can't think of any off the top of my head).  You just need to know what you're doing.

Comment: @LevLevitsky I always use a mnemonic to remember that "`is` compares address while `==` compares value". I haven't gone wrong any day using this mnemonic. Going by that, changing the implementation of `is` is like faking another address.

Comment: @mgilson If you go by other languages, or `Java` for instance, `a == null` means the value (or pointer value) of `a` is really just a special literal called `null`, which is neither an instance nor value comparable to anything. Python lacks that, and the `None` is a singleton instance of the `NoneType` class. 
`a  == None` would just be crazy because I could override `__eq__` and make it equal to `None` every time even when it isn't. Meanwhile `a is None` is simply try to equate the address of a singleton object that is supposed to represent all null objects in the world.

Comment: @mgilson So you see, idiomatically in Python `a is None` makes correct sense than `a == None`.

Comment: @JohnStrood Python's `id(a) == id(None)` is equivalent both to `a is None` and Java's `a == null`. This does not have anything to do with absolute correctness. I'm most cases you will want to use `is`. That in no way means that there aren't cases where `==` makes more conceptual sense. Not being able to think of one is merely a failure of imagination, not a rule of the universe.

Comment: -1 because the question is not answered. The question is "should I use....". But what is the answer ? a long "this is how it works", while it should be "you should ....". In the end the primary question is not even answered. The second question "Is 'myvar is None' prefered and if so why", has no answer either.

Comment: Hrmm ... Not sure I understand.  I think the first sentence answers the question:

`Use "is" when you want to check against an object's identity (e.g. checking to see if var is None)`.  I state the guiding principle and then the example is a direct answer to OP's question.

Answer (score 191):

`is` is generally preferred when comparing arbitrary objects to singletons like `None` because it is faster and more predictable. `is` always compares by object identity, whereas what `==` will do depends on the exact type of the operands and even on their ordering.

This recommendation is supported by [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008), which [explicitly states](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) that "comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with `is` or `is not`, never the equality operators."

Comment: Thanks for posting this; the accepted answer makes some interesting points, but yours responds to the question much more directly.

Comment: It seems weird to rely on what is essentially an implementation detail. Why should I care how many instances of NoneType there are?

Comment: @BallpointBen Because it's *not* an implementation detail - there is only one `None` object under the global constant `None`. If anything, the `NoneType` is an implementation detail because the `None` singleton must have *some* type. (The fact that you cannot create instances of this type is a good indication that its one instance is intended to be a singleton.)

Comment: @BallpointBen I think the key point is that Python possesses a strong concept of object identity. If you want to check whether an object compares _equal_ to `None`, by all means use `obj == None`. If you want to check whether an object *is* `None`, use `obj is None`. The point of the PEP 8 recommendation (and of this answer) is that most people want the latter when they want to check for None, and it also happens to be faster and clearer.

Comment: `None` is also different than cached objects like `0` and other small integers, where the caching really is an implementation detail. The difference there is that an integer has intrinsic value which gives its properties and it can be calculated. On the other hand, `None` has no state whatsoever, it's only its *identity* that matters and makes it special.

Answer (score 12):

PEP 8 defines that it is better to use the `is` operator when comparing singletons.

Comment: I don't see anywhere where PEP8 justifies this recommendation. Do you have a link?

Comment: @BT https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations

Answer (score 5):

I recently encountered where this can go wrong.

```
import numpy as np
nparray = np.arange(4)

# Works
def foo_is(x=None):
    if x is not None:
        print(x[1])

foo_is()
foo_is(nparray)

# Code below raises 
# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
def foo_eq(x=None):
    if x != None:
        print(x[1])

foo_eq()
foo_eq(nparray)
```

I created a function that optionally takes a numpy array as argument and changes if it is included. If I test for its inclusion using inequality operators `!=`, this raises a ValueError (see code above). If I use `is not none`, the code works correctly.

Comment: Based on the error you're getting.. this has nothing to do with `None`. It has to do with the fact that you're comparing an array to none. Its the array causing your problem, not `None`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say? That's the whole point? That if you just want to check whether it is (exactly) None, it will always work out with `is` even if the provided value is of a completely different type (e.g. an array). Whereas the equality operators are only defined for the same type.

Answer (score 2):

A useful tidbit to add to people's understanding.

The reason that we check for *identity* with `None` is because Python only ever stores the value `None` in one place in memory, and every object which equals `None` has its value stored in this same location. There are a handful of "special values" which get this treatment, and `None` is just one of them.

But most values do not get this special treatment! For example, the float 1.25 can be stored in different locations in memory:

```
a = None
b = None
a is b
```

True

```
a = 1.25
b = 1.25
a is b
```

False

It just so happens that `None` is among the handful of values which are always stored in one place in memory. Another example is any integer between `-5` and `256`... since these integers are used often, they are always stored in memory, and every integer with that value is stored in the same place in your computer's memory! Try it out:

```
a = 256
b = 256
a is b
```

True

```
a = 257
b = 257
a is b
```

False

So you can think of `None` as being part of a special class of values which always have a constant memory address. That is why we can use `is` to check whether two variables are both `None`... it just checks whether the memory address is the same.

Edit: Joooeey makes the good point that which integers are stored in memory is specific to your python implementation, and the example of numbers from `-5` to `256` is specific to CPython. If you don't know what you're running, it's probably CPython, which is the most common implementation. But for this reason (and others) it is better practice to compare equality between these numbers with `a == 2` and **not** with `a is 2`. As for `None`, it is specified to be the sole instance of the `NoneType` type according to the [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#None) itself, so regardless of implementation you can always compare it using `a is None`.

Comment: The examples about floats and integers apply specifically to the CPython implementation of Python. `None` however is defined as a singleton in the Python language spec: https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#None

Answer (score -2):

Another instance where "==" differs from "is". When you pull information from a database and check if a value exists, the result will be either a value or None.

Look at the if and else below. Only "is" works when the database returns "None". If you put == instead, the if statement won't work, it will go straight to else, even though the result is "None". Hopefully, I am making myself clear.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
row = itemID_box.get()

# pull data to be logged so that the deletion is recorded
query = "SELECT itemID, item, description FROM items WHERE itemID LIKE '%" + row + "%'"
c.execute(query)
result = c.fetchone()

if result is None:
    # log the deletion in the app.log file
    logging = logger('Error')
    logging.info(f'The deletion of {row} failed.')
    messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "The record number is invalid")
else:
    # execute the deletion
    c.execute("DELETE from items WHERE itemID = " + row)
    itemID_box.delete(0, tk.END)
    messagebox.showinfo("Warning", "The record has been deleted")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```