# Convert python list with None values to numpy array with nan values

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to convert a list that contains numeric values and `None` values to `numpy.array`, such that `None` is replaces with `numpy.nan`.

For example:

```
my_list = [3,5,6,None,6,None]

# My desired result: 
my_array = numpy.array([3,5,6,np.nan,6,np.nan])
```

Naive approach fails:

```
>>> my_list
[3, 5, 6, None, 6, None]
>>> np.array(my_list)
array([3, 5, 6, None, 6, None], dtype=object) # very limited 
>>> _ * 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'

>>> my_array # normal array can handle these operations
array([  3.,   5.,   6.,  nan,   6.,  nan])
>>> my_array * 2
array([  6.,  10.,  12.,  nan,  12.,  nan])
```

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You simply have to explicitly declare the data type:

```
>>> my_list = [3, 5, 6, None, 6, None]
>>> np.array(my_list, dtype=np.float)
array([  3.,   5.,   6.,  nan,   6.,  nan])
```

Comment: I had a feeling that I was missing something simple...Thank You

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it only works for float for which nan is defined and not for dtype int.

Comment: Please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339214/initializing-numpy-masked-array-from-python-int-list-with-none-values on that problem exactly.

Comment: Justy a heads-up that ```np.float``` is deprecated. use ```dtype=float``` instead

Comment: Interestingly this turns them to plain python float `nan`, not `np.nan`. I wonder why as it may seem a little irregular, even though both types of nan qualify the same under `np.isnan()` . This is so even when using `dtype=np.float64` which is explicitly a numpy data type. [This conversion is not even explicitly documented for np.array()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)

Comment: DeprecationWarning: `np.float` is a deprecated alias for the builtin `float`

Answer (score 7):

What about

```
my_array = np.array(map(lambda x: numpy.nan if x==None else x, my_list))
```

Comment: I'd say `x is None` as == might be more [quirky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247373/python-none-comparison-should-i-use-is-or)

Comment: What worked for me was  `my_array = np.array(list(map(lambda x: np.nan if x is None else x, my_list)))`