# Initializing numpy masked array from Python int list with None values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

As shown in the answer to the question [Convert python list with None values to numpy array with nan values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456239/convert-python-list-with-none-values-to-numpy-array-with-nan-values), it is straightforward to initialize a masked numpy array from a list with None values if we enforce the dtype=float. Those float values get converted to nan and we can simply do:

```
ma.masked_invalid(np.array(a, dtype=float), copy=False)
```

This however will not work for int like:

```
ma.masked_invalid(np.array(a, dtype=int), copy=False)
```

since the intermediate np.array will not be created with None values (there is no int nan).

What is the most efficient way to initialize a masked array based on Python list of ints that also contains None values in such way that those None values become masked?

Comment: I don't think there's going to be a good way to do this without a temporary array of object dtype. Make sure the solution you pick doesn't wind up with an object dtype at the end of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most elegant solution I have found so far (and it is not elegant at all) is to initialize a masked array of type `float` and convert it to `int` afterwards:

```
ma.masked_invalid(np.array(a, dtype=float), copy=False).astype(int)
```

This generates a proper NP array where `None` values in the initial array `a` are masked. For instance, for:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, None, 4]
ma.masked_invalid(np.array(a, dtype=float), copy=False).astype(int)
```

we get:

```
masked_array(data = [1 2 3 -- 4],
             mask = [False False False  True False],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Also, the actual masked int values become min int, i.e.

```
ma.masked_invalid(np.array(column, dtype=float), copy=False).astype(int).data
```

gives:

```
array([                   1,                    2,                    3,
       -9223372036854775808,                    4])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't,  however you can create a numpy array of `object dtype` cells

```py
ma.masked_invalid(np.array(a, dtype=object), copy=False)
```

**EDIT**

Otherwise You can take a look here [NumPy or Pandas: Keeping array type as integer while having a NaN value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548005/numpy-or-pandas-keeping-array-type-as-integer-while-having-a-nan-value)

Comment: Yes, but I do want int eventually. The complete answer should provide me with a masked array of type int. What's the most efficient way to achieve that?

Comment: It seems that nan's still did not make it to numpy int. What's the best way through object then?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this by first creating two empty arrays, one with data type `int` that will become the mask**ed** array and another with data type bool that will become the mask itself.

Then we traverse the Python array. In the `arr_without_none` we replace all occurrences of `None` with the default value and in `mask_mat` we store whether the original value in the Python array was `None` or an integer. At the end we produce a masked array out of these two components.

```
def masked_int_array(arr, default=0):
    arr_without_none = numpy.empty(len(arr), dtype=int)
    mask_mat = numpy.empty(len(arr), dtype=bool)
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        arr_without_none[i] = default if arr[i] is None else arr[i]
        mask_mat[i] = arr[i] is None
    return ma.array(data=arr_without_none, dtype=int, mask=mask_mat, copy=False)
```