# Implementation of NoneType, Reasons and Details

Tags: python, python-3.x, singleton, nonetype, python-internals

I recently read somewhere that the special value `None` in python is a singleton object of its own class, specifically `NoneType`. This explained a lot, since most errors involving `None` in python produce `AttributeError`s instead of some special "NoneError" or something.

Since all of these `AttributeErrors` reflected the attributes that `NoneType` lacked, I became intrigued by what attributes `NoneType` *did* have, if any.

I decided to look into this `NoneType` and learn more about it. I've always found the best way to learn about a new language feature is to use it, so I tried instantiating `NoneType` in IDLE:

```
>>> n = NoneType()
```

This produced an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    n = NoneType()
NameError: name 'NoneType' is not defined
```

Confused, I inspected `None` to see if I'd gotten the type name correct. Sure enough,

```
>>> type(None)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Now very confused, I did a quick google search. This revealed that [for some reason NoneType was somehow removed in Python 3.](http://bugs.python.org/issue19438)

Well I though, ha ha! I can work around this by storing the type of `None` in a variable, since [classes are objects in python.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/100146/1530508) This seemed to work:

```
>>> NoneType = type(None)
>>> n = NoneType()
```

And when I printed n, I got pretty much what I was expecting:

```
>>> print(n)
None
```

But then this happened:

```
>>> n is None
True
```

And:

```
>>> id(n)
506768776
>>> id(None)
506768776
```

My variable `n` IS `None`. Not only the same type as `None`. It IS `None`. This is not what I expected.

I tried using `dis` to get more info on `NoneType`, but when I called

```
>>> dis.dis(type(None))
```

It produced no output.

I then then tried investigating the `__new__` method, which several users had mentioned in the comments:

```
dis.dis(type(None).__new__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    dis.dis(type(None).__new__)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\dis.py", line 59, in dis
    type(x).__name__)
TypeError: don't know how to disassemble builtin_function_or_method objects
>>>
```

More errors.

Here are my questions:

- Why is `n` the exact same Object as `None`?
- Why was the language designed such that `n` is the exact same Object as `None`?
- How would one even implement this behavior in python?

Comment: None type itself is implemented in C. However, you can do something similar by overriding __new__ in a Python class. Which allows you to customize object creation.

Comment: There's also `type(NotImplemented)() is NotImplemented`, `bool() is False`, `bool(1) is True`, and `type(Ellipsis)() is Ellipsis`. Of those, only the `bool` type is actually added to `builtins` since it's used to convert an object to an explicit `False` or `True` boolean value.

Comment: CPython's C API has macros for these singleton objects: `Py_None`, `Py_NotImplemented`, `Py_False`, `Py_True`, and `Py_Ellipsis`. Making them singletons allows using a quick identity check.

Comment: FYI, creating an instance of an object that way doesn't necessarily have to return a unique instance. Object creation can be controlled by implementing `__new__()` for the type. In this case, you could look at its implementation as returning the same instance of the object always.

Comment: There is no built-in name bound to the `NoneType` type, but you can import one from the `types` modules: `types.NoneType`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why is `n` the exact same Object as `None`?**

The C implementation keeps a singleton instance.  `NoneType.__new__` is returning the singleton instance.

**Why was the language designed such that n is the exact same Object as `None`?**

If there was not a singleton instance, then you could not rely on the check `x is None` since the `is` operator is based on identity.  Although `None == None` is also `True`, it's possible to have `x == None` be `True` when `x` is not actually `None`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14247383/1464861) for an example.

**How would one even implement this behavior in python?**

You can implement this pattern by overridding `__new__`.  Here's a basic example:

```
class Singleton(object):
  _instance = None
  def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    if Singleton._instance is None:
      Singleton._instance = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    return Singleton._instance

if __name__ == '__main__':
  s1 = Singleton()
  s2 = Singleton()
  print 's1 is s2:', s1 is s2
  print 'id(s1):', id(s1)
  print 'id(s2):', id(s2)
```

Output:

> s1 is s2: True 
>   id(s1): 4506243152 
>   id(s2): 4506243152

Of course this simple example doesn't make it *impossible* to create a second instance.

Comment: It says in the tags that I'm using Python 3. (3.3, to be precise).

Comment: Sure, so you're getting the singleton instance as mentioned for that part, was just pointing out the change.  The rest of the answer applies to both versions.

Comment: Ok, removed the 2.x bit.

Answer (score 7):

Other answers describe how to use `__new__` to implement a singleton, but that's not how None is actually implemented (in cPython at least, I haven't looked into other implementations).

Trying to create an instance of None through `type(None)()` is special cased, and ends up calling the [following C function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8b4d36d0c090/Objects/object.c#l1409):

```
static PyObject *
none_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs)
{
    if (PyTuple_GET_SIZE(args) || (kwargs && PyDict_Size(kwargs))) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "NoneType takes no arguments");
        return NULL;
    }
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

And `Py_RETURN_NONE` is [defined here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8b4d36d0c090/Include/object.h#l837):

```
/*
_Py_NoneStruct is an object of undefined type which can be used in contexts
where NULL (nil) is not suitable (since NULL often means 'error').

Don't forget to apply Py_INCREF() when returning this value!!!
*/
PyAPI_DATA(PyObject) _Py_NoneStruct; /* Don't use this directly */
#define Py_None (&_Py_NoneStruct)

/* Macro for returning Py_None from a function */
#define Py_RETURN_NONE return Py_INCREF(Py_None), Py_None
```

Contrast this with the [function that creates a normal python object](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8b4d36d0c090/Objects/object.c#l237):

```
PyObject *
_PyObject_New(PyTypeObject *tp)
{
    PyObject *op;
    op = (PyObject *) PyObject_MALLOC(_PyObject_SIZE(tp));
    if (op == NULL)
        return PyErr_NoMemory();
    return PyObject_INIT(op, tp);
}
```

When you create a normal object, memory for the object is allocated and initialized. When you try to create a new instance of `None`, all you get is a reference to the already existing `_Py_NoneStruct`. That's why, no matter what you do, every reference to `None` will be the exact same object.

Comment: Let me know if you need more clarification or if you aren't familiar with C code.

Comment: +1 for the detailed C explanation, but I chose to accept another answer as it gave a more complete response concerning all of my questions.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is n the exact same Object as None?

Many immutable objects in Python are [interned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) including `None`, smaller ints, and many strings.

Demo:

```
>>> s1='abc'
>>> s2='def'
>>> s3='abc'
>>> id(s1)
4540177408
>>> id(s3)
4540177408    # Note: same as s1
>>> x=1
>>> y=2
>>> z=1
>>> id(x)
4538711696
>>> id(z)
4538711696    # Note: same as x
```

> Why was the language designed
>   such that n is the exact same Object as None?

See above -- speed, efficiency, lack of ambiguity and memory usage among other reasons to intern immutable objects.

> How would one even
>   implement this behavior in python?

Among other ways, you can override `__new__` to return the same object:

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(
                                cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance
```

For strings, you can call [intern](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#intern) on Python 2 or [sys.intern](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sys.html#sys.intern) on Python 3

Comment: Interning has the same effect, but a different principle.

Answer (score 0):

1. The NoneType overrides `__new__` which always return the same singleton. The code is actually [written in C](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b35b204e5d0b/Objects/object.c#l1412) so `dis` cannot help, but conceptually it's just like this.
2. Having only one None instance is easier to deal with. They are all equal anyway.
3. By overriding `__new__`... e.g.

   ```
   class MyNoneType(object):
       _common_none = 0
       def __new__(cls):
           return cls._common_none

   MyNoneType._common_none = object.__new__(MyNoneType)

   m1 = MyNoneType()
   m2 = MyNoneType()
   print(m1 is m2)
   ```