# How to assign a NULL value to a pointer in python?

Tags: python

I am C programmer. I am new to python. In C , when we define the structure of a binary tree node we assign NULL to it's right and left child as :

```
struct node 
{
    int val;  
    struct node *right ;  
    struct node *left ;  
};
```

And when initializing a node , we write as :

```
val = some_value  
right = NULL;  
left = NULL;
```

Now my question is: how can we assign a NULL value to right and left pointers of the node in Python?

And how can we test against the Python version of NULL ? In C it would be:

```
if( ptr->right == NULL )
```

Thank you!

Comment: [`None`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#None)

Comment: `None`, and `is None`.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

All objects in python are implemented via references so the distinction between objects and pointers to objects does not exist in source code.

The python equivalent of `NULL` is called [`None`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#None) (good info [here](http://www.pythoncentral.io/python-null-equivalent-none/)). As all objects in python are implemented via references, you can re-write your struct to look like this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self): #object initializer to set attributes (fields)
        self.val = 0
        self.right = None
        self.left = None
```

And then it works pretty much like you would expect:

```
node = Node()
node.val = some_val #always use . as everything is a reference and -> is not used
node.left = Node()
```

Note that unlike in `NULL` in C, `None` is not a "pointer to nowhere": it is actually the only instance of `class NoneType`.
Therefore, as `None` is a regular object, you can test for it just like any other object with `node.left == None`. However, since [`None` is a singleton instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20833081/1530508), it [is considered more idiomatic](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) to use `is` and compare for reference equality:

```
if node.left is None:
   print("The left node is None/Null.")
```

Answer (score 9):

```
left = None

left is None #evaluates to True
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can use `None`, but you can also use `objc.NULL`, e.g.

```
import objc
val = objc.NULL
```

Especially useful when working with C code in Python.

Also see: [Python objc.NULL Examples](http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/56771/objc.NULL)

Comment: Link is dead. Is [this](https://pyobjc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/module-objc.html#objc.NULL) the current documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Also, I believe just testing the object itself without a comparrison, validates agains null/None. so:

```
if val is null:
```

would be equal to:

```
if val:
```