# Why Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or is not?

Tags: python, pep8

In PEP 8 standard, [here](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), what is the reason for the following recommendation: "Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or is not, never the equality operators."

Comment: For one, it makes the intent more clear. The test `is` for two values *being* the same object, not merely being value-equal. Furthermore, `==` is always true if `is` is true (but the opposite is not always true).

Comment: Also see: [Python None comparison: should I use “is” or ==?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247373/python-none-comparison-should-i-use-is-or)

Comment: is does an object comparison; you might get inconsistent answers with ==

Answer (score 1):

`==` and `!=` are *equality test*, they invoke the `__eq__` method to check if the left hand side of the operator represent an object identical to the one on the right hand side.

`is` and `is not` are *identity tests*, they check whether the left hand side and the right hand side of the operator reference the **same** object.

*identity tests* are preferred for singleton objects because:

1. They prevent other object to mimic the singleton one:

   ```
   class FakeNone:
       def __eq__(self, other):
           return other is None

   print FakeNone() is None        # False
   print FakeNone() == None        # True ... WHAT?
   ```
2. They are slightly faster since they do not need to invoke methods.

Comment: I'm not convinced by reason #1, why would anyone do that without good reason?  It's like saying we should use `is` instead of `==` for small integers and interned strings, to prevent someone from mimicking equality of those, which is of course absurd because it is useful that `0 == 0.` etc.

Comment: I think this is a good answer. If a `FakeNone` was ever necessary, then of course comparing it to `None` with `==` would have a use case, but as a general rule I think if you want to see if something *is* `None` then using `is None` is what you want. For example, say there is a case where you want to distinguish between `FakeNone` and `None`.

Answer (score -2):

Probably performance reasons. **is** comparison is comparing the id directly without invoking **eq** of the object.