# Basic Python Loop: Max and Min from User Input

Tags: python

I'm trying to create an program in python for a class and I can't figure out why I can't get the expected output.
The program is to take user input values until a 'done' is entered, and then print the max and min of these values.  It also has some error checking for valid input (number and not text).

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    inp = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if inp == "done" : 
        break
    try:
        num=float(inp)
    except:
        print "Invalid input"
        continue

    if inp>largest: 
        largest=inp
    if inp<smallest: 
        smallest=inp

print "Maximum is ", largest
print "Minimum is ", smallest
```

The loop breaks properly if 'done' is inserted.  It doesn't fail if a text string is entered, but also doesn't print "Invalid input".  I'm not asking for someone to solve my homework program, but to provide me with an explanation as to why I never get largest or smallest to be anything other than their original assignment of "None".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
largest = None
smallest = None
num = None

while True:
    inp = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if inp == "done" : 
        break
    try:
        num=float(inp)
    except:
        print ("Invalid input")
        continue

    if largest is None:
        largest = num
        smallest = num

    if num>largest: 
        largest=num
    if num<smallest: 
        smallest=num

print ("Maximum is ", largest)
print ("Minimum is ", smallest)
```

Comment: Thanks Shahkalpesh.  I did finally get a variation similar to your modified version to work!

Comment: OP's looking for an explanation, but where is it? Just a sentence or two should do.

Answer (score 2):

```
if smallest is None or smallest< inp:
    smallest=inp
if largest is None or largest > inp:
    largest=inp
```

You need to do something with your comparison operators bro. Right now you're checking if *smallest* is smaller than input (and vice versa for *largest*). The result: you're switching max and min. Should've been like this:

```
if smallest is None or inp < smallest:
    smallest = inp
if largest is None or inp > largest:
    largest = inp
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't report the proper max or min because you use `inp` (the string) in your comparisons instead of `num` (the float).

Comment: I'm brand new to Python, so I am likely wrong.
Scott, I don't think that is correct.  The try:except statement checks for correct input.  If that fails, it starts over.  If it does't fail, then the input must have been a number and thus valid for comparison.   

Please let me know if that isn't correct.

Comment: This is not so much incorrect as incomplete (see the accepted answer); comparing different types doesn't necessarily raise an exception, but probably doesn't produce the answer you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is the final code I used. With help from all of you that responded!  Thanks to all for their time.

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    inp = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if inp == "done" : 
        break
    try:
        num=float(inp)
    except:
        print ("Invalid input")
        continue

    if smallest is None or smallest< inp:
        smallest=inp
    if largest is None or largest > inp:
        largest=inp

print ("Maximum is ", largest)
print ("Minimum is ", smallest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use None as your initialization, use floats.

```
largest =float("-inf") # negative infinity
smallest = float("inf") # infinity
while True:
    inp = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if inp == "done" : 
        break
    try:
        num = float(inp)
        largest = max(largest, num)
        smallest = min(smallest, num)
    except:
        print "Invalid input"
        continue

print "Maximum is ", largest
print "Minimum is ", smallest
```

Comment: Thank you Robert.  I got your code to work by then converting the largest smallest to integers before printing.  I also finally figured out how to use the None function by utilizing :
if smallest is None or smallest< inp:
        smallest=inp
    if largest is None or largest > inp:
        largest=inp

Thanks to all who helped.

Comment: Your welcome. If you liked the help, please "upvote" or mark answers as correct. It is how the community works :)

Comment: I don't have my 15 rep yet.  I marked it up, but...it won't activate until I get 15 points.

Comment: Well then... Woo hoo!

Comment: Technically speaking, `largest` should be initialized to `float("-inf")` since it would fail for any input consisting entirely of negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break

    try:
        num = int(num)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue

    if smallest == None or num < smallest:
        smallest = num
    if largest == None or num > largest:
        largest = num

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Comment: You need to add context and comment your code. See the topic [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the help center.

Comment: This is practically a duplicate of [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35154640/4518341) except that it's updated for Python 3 and uses the name `num` instead of `inp`.

Comment: Don't compare to `None` with `==`, use `is` instead ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14247373/4518341)). It doesn't make a difference in this case, but it's good practice.

Answer (score -1):

It works, kinda

```
python27 test.py
Enter a number: 10
Enter a number: 20
Enter a number: 40
Enter a number: done
Maximum is  40
Minimum is  None
```

You will never get a min because a float is never less than None.

Comment: I used the logic of:
if inp is None or inp < smallest:
    smallest=inp

And that didn't work

Comment: Also like @scott said, you should also be using `num` and not `imp` because `num` is your parsed input.