# Printing same HTTPResponse Object returns different outputs - Python

Tags: python, httpresponse

```
def crawl(url):
    html = getHTML(url) # getHTML() retruns HTTPResponse
    print(html.read()) # PRINT STATMENT 1
    if (html == None):
        print("Error getting HTML")
    else:
        # parse html
        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
        # print data
        try:
            print(bsObj.h1.get_text())
        except AttributeError as e:
            print(e)

        print(html.read()) # PRINT STAETMENT 2
```

What I don't understand is..

**PRINT STATEMENT 1** prints the whole html whereas **PRINT STATEMENT 2** prints only `b''`

What is happening here? ..I'm quite new to Python.

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't do `html == None`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247373/python-none-comparison-should-i-use-is-or.

Comment: @edwinksl ty.. that is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`html` is an HTTPResponse object. HTTPResponse supports file-like operations, such as `read()`.

Just like when reading a file, a `read()` consumes the available data and moves the file pointer to the **end** of the file/data. A subsequent `read()` has nothing to return.

You have two options:

1. Reset the file pointer to the beginning after reading using the `seek()` method:

   ```
   print(html.read())
   html.seek(0) # moves the file pointer to byte 0 relative to the start of the file/data
   ```
2. Save the result instead:

   ```
   html_body = html.read()
   print(html_body)
   ```

Typically, you would use the second option as it'll be easier to re-use `html_body`