# How to count number of words that start with 'W' in a binary search tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, binary-search-tree, counting

I have to make a function that counts the number of words that start with 'W' in my binary search tree. Right now, my program is returning 0 even though there is one word that starts with W.

This is my code:

```
def countNodes(tree):
    count = 0 

    if tree == None:
        return count

    if tree['left'] != None:
        if tree['data'][1][0] == 'w' or tree['data'][1][0] == 'W':   
            return count+1

    if tree['right'] != None:
         if (tree['data'][1][0] == 'w' or tree['data'][1][0] == 'W'):
            return count+1

    countNodes(tree['left'])
    countNodes(tree['right'])
    return count

def main():
    myTree = None  #create an empty tree
    #Create a tree with the nodes [20, 2, 25, 14, 1, 23, 75, 93, 74]
    #Note that the add function always returns the root of the BST!
    myTree = add(myTree, [20, "Jenna"])
    myTree = add(myTree, [2, "Wendy"])
    myTree = add(myTree, [25, "Layla"])
    myTree = add(myTree, [14, "Robert"])
    myTree = add(myTree, [1, "Jamie"])
    myTree = add(myTree, [23, "Stephanie"])
    myTree = add(myTree, [75, "Jay"])
    myTree = add(myTree, [93, "Barbara"])
    myTree = add(myTree, [74, "John"])

    print(countNodes(myTree))
```

Comment: don't return after the second `if`, return at the end (after testing both sides) only.

Comment: You are not capturing the value returned by `countNodes()` inside `countNodes` method

Comment: and call your function recursively too...

Comment: How is the binary tree ordered? By name or number? If it's by name you can use that so that you only follow one of the children making it O(log n)

Comment: use `is None`/`is not None` instead of `== None`/`!= None`, some explanation can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247373/python-none-comparison-should-i-use-is-or)

Answer (score 2):

So the only thing you need to change is your recursing function lines:

```
countNodes(tree['left'])
countNodes(tree['right'])
```

Instead, do this:

```
count += countNodes(tree['left'])
count += countNodes(tree['right'])
```

You also don't need to return when you find a W, you just need to iterate your counter:

```
count = 0 

if tree == None:
    return count



if tree['left'] != None:
    if tree['data'][1][0] == 'w' or tree['data'][1][0] == 'W':

        count += 1


if tree['right'] != None:
     if (tree['data'][1][0] == 'w' or tree['data'][1][0] == 'W'):

        count += 1


count += countNodes(tree['left'])
count += countNodes(tree['right'])
return count
```

That way you'll know if you have more than 1 name starting with W.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the base case, which is that there is no tree, return 0 then,  otherwise check if your word starts with the letter and recurse over the tree branches.

```
def countNodes(tree):
    if tree == None:
        return 0
    count = 1 if tree["data"][1].startswith("W") else 0
    return count + countNodes(tree["left"]) + countNodes(tree["right"])
```

I would sugest that you have an extra argument for the checking value:

```
def countNodes(tree, toCheck):
    if tree == None:
        return 0
    count = 1 if tree["data"][1].startswith(toCheck) else 0
    return count + countNodes(tree["left"], toCheck) + countNodes(tree["right"], toCheck)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because code of the Node class is missing in the code coming along with the question I took some from [here](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/binary-search-tree-library-in-python/) and adapted it to the provided data:

```
class Node:
    """
    Tree node: left and right child + data which can be any object
    """
    def __init__(self, data=(0,' ')):
        """
        Node constructor

        @param data node data object
        """
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data

    def insert(self, data):
        """
        Insert new node with data
        @param data node data object to insert
        """
        if self.data:
            if data < self.data:
                if self.left is None:
                    self.left = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.left.insert(data)
            elif data > self.data:
                if self.right is None:
                    self.right = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.right.insert(data)
        else:
            self.data = data 

    def lookup(self, data, parent=None):
        """
        Lookup node containing data
        @param data node data object to look up
        @param parent node's parent
        @returns node and node's parent if found or None, None
        """
        if data < self.data:
            if self.left is None:
                return None, None
            return self.left.lookup(data, self)
        elif data > self.data:
            if self.right is None:
                return None, None
            return self.right.lookup(data, self)
        else:
            return self, parent

    def delete(self, data):
        """
        Delete node containing data

        @param data node's content to delete
        """
        # get node containing data
        node, parent = self.lookup(data)
        if node is not None:
            children_count = node.children_count()

        if children_count == 0:
            # if node has no children, just remove it
            if parent:
                if parent.left is node:
                    parent.left = None
                else:
                    parent.right = None
                del node
            else:
                self.data = None
        elif children_count == 1:
            # if node has 1 child
            # replace node with its child
            if node.left:
                n = node.left
            else:
                n = node.right
            if parent:
                if parent.left is node:
                    parent.left = n
                else:
                    parent.right = n
                del node
            else:
                self.left = n.left
                self.right = n.right
                self.data = n.data
        else:
             # if node has 2 children
             # find its successor
             parent = node
             successor = node.right
             while successor.left:
                 parent = successor
                 successor = successor.left
             # replace node data by its successor data
             node.data = successor.data
             # fix successor's parent's child
             if parent.left == successor:
                 parent.left = successor.right
             else:
                 parent.right = successor.right 

    def print_tree(self):
        """
        Print tree content inorder
        """
        if self.left:
            self.left.print_tree()
        print( self.data, end='')
        if self.right:
            self.right.print_tree()

    def children_count(self):
        """
        Returns the number of children

        @returns number of children: 0, 1, 2
        """
        cnt = 0
        if self.left:
            cnt += 1
        if self.right:
            cnt += 1
        return cnt

    def compare_trees(self, node):
        """
        Compare 2 trees

        @param node tree's root node to compare to
        @returns True if the tree passed is identical to this tree
        """
        if node is None:
            return False
        if self.data != node.data:
            return False
        res = True
        if self.left is None:
            if node.left:
                return False
        else:
            res = self.left.compare_trees(node.left)
        if res is False:
            return False
        if self.right is None:
            if node.right:
                return False
        else:
            res = self.right.compare_trees(node.right)
        return res

    def tree_data(self):
        """
        Generator to get the tree nodes data
        """
        # we use a stack to traverse the tree in a non-recursive way
        stack = []
        node = self
        while stack or node: 
            if node:
                stack.append(node)
                node = node.left
            else: # we are returning so we pop the node and we yield it
                node = stack.pop()
                yield node.data
                node = node.right

#:class node()


def countNodes(tree):
    count = 0
    if tree.data[1][0].upper() == 'W':
        count += 1
    print("visitingNode", tree.data, "count", count, "tree.data[1]", tree.data[1])
    if tree.left == None and tree.right==None:
        return count
    if tree.left != None:
        count += countNodes(tree.left)
    if tree.right != None:
        count += countNodes(tree.right)
    return count


def main():
    myTree = Node()  #create an empty tree
    #Create a tree with the nodes [20, 2, 25, 14, 1, 23, 75, 93, 74]
    #Note that the add function always returns the root of the BST!
    myTree.insert((20, "Jenna"))
    myTree.insert((2, "Wendy"))
    myTree.insert((25, "Layla"))
    myTree.insert((14, "Robert"))
    myTree.insert((1, "Jamie"))
    myTree.insert((23, "Stephanie"))
    myTree.insert((75, "Jay"))
    myTree.insert((93, "Barbara"))
    myTree.insert((74, "John"))

    print("Number of names beginning with 'W' or 'w':", countNodes(myTree))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

The `countNodes()` function in the code above works as expected and prints:

```
visitingNode (0, ' ') count 0 tree.data[1]  
visitingNode (20, 'Jenna') count 0 tree.data[1] Jenna
visitingNode (2, 'Wendy') count 1 tree.data[1] Wendy
visitingNode (1, 'Jamie') count 0 tree.data[1] Jamie
visitingNode (14, 'Robert') count 0 tree.data[1] Robert
visitingNode (25, 'Layla') count 0 tree.data[1] Layla
visitingNode (23, 'Stephanie') count 0 tree.data[1] Stephanie
visitingNode (75, 'Jay') count 0 tree.data[1] Jay
visitingNode (74, 'John') count 0 tree.data[1] John
visitingNode (93, 'Barbara') count 0 tree.data[1] Barbara
Number of names beginning with 'W' or 'w': 1
```

Notice that `if tree.data[1][0].upper() == 'W':` is enough to test for both cases 'W' and 'w' and that it makes no sense to branch down to nodes which anyway aren't there (when .left is None or .right is None). This makes the code of 'countNodes()' a bit shorter and easier to follow.