# Summing nodes in binary tree (python) - TypeError: 'NoneType'

Tags: python, binary-tree, nonetype

I am trying to sum up the nodes in a binary tree:

```
def average(tree):
   if tree is None:
       return
   total = (tree['data']) + (average(tree['left'])) + (average(tree['right']))
   print(total)
```

I also tried with "is" and "is not" however it still gave me the following error:

```
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: The bare `return` returns `None`, so your check is basically useless. Perhaps return a default _integer_ value such as `0`. Also, it should be `if tree is None:` with `is` rather than `==`.

Comment: You also need to `return total`. Also, recommend you don't use `sum` as your function name, it hides python's builtin `sum`.

Comment: @Christian Dean why not `==` or even `not`?

Comment: @t.m.adam _"why not `==` "_ - See [Python None comparison: should I use “is” or ==?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247373/python-none-comparison-should-i-use-is-or).

Comment: I changed it to:

def average(tree):
    if tree is None:
        return 0 
    else:
        total = tree['data'] + average(tree['left']) + average(tree['right'])

But it still doesn't work

Comment: @Christian Dean it was a nice read, but i don't think it's important for this case.

Comment: You also need to do what @AChampion said. `return total`.

Comment: @t.m.adam Why not? The official Python style guide [PEP8 says to do this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations): _"Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or is not, never the equality operators."_. Not that you must always rigidly follow the style guide, but for cases such as this it's best to. Not only is it faster to use `is`, but it's the commonly accepted idiom and thus makes his code more readable to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here which have to do with taking care to return values once they have been calculated from `average`.

First, in your code the lone `return` statement will return the non-numeric `None` value. This is an issue as when you get any node without two child nodes (e.g. a leaf), `tree['left']` or/and `tree['right']` will return `None`. This `None` is passed to `average`, which returns `None` back. The error you are getting is due to subsequenly trying to add this returned value on the 3rd line of the function. To fix this, you can simply return a "base case" value for what should the "average" of a tree that is empty be.

Second, even in the case where `average` is called recursively on a child node that is not `None`, `average` will *still* return `None` because as there is no other return statement in the function, and in Python when evaluation reaches the end of a function without a return statement there is an implicit return of `None`. To fix this simply return the `total` that you have calculated!

Fixing these two problems might look like the following:

```
def average(tree):
   if tree is None:
       return 0
   total = tree['data'] + average(tree['left']) + average(tree['right'])
   return total
```

although I can't say for certain that returning zero in the base case is the best for exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

As a final note, you may want to add a check that `tree['data']` is not `None` to rule out edge cases where nodes have no data!

Comment: Thank you so much!