# How to distinguish np.ndarray or None?

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is the code:

```
import numpy as np

def check(x):
    if x == None:
        print('x is None')

check(np.array([1,2]))
```

`x` can be None or np.ndarray, so I want to check whether `x` is None or np.ndarray, but if I pass np.ndarray into `check`, it will raise a error,
because np.ndarray==None should use `np.any()` or `np.all()`. So what should I do?

Comment: Identity comparison: `if x is None:`. [The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247373/python-none-comparison-should-i-use-is-or) mentions your case specifically – objects that override `__eq__` and behave surprisingly when compared to for example None.

Comment: @IljaEverilä You should make this the answer.

Comment: @HankGay I've tried to find a better dupe target for this, which the link from before almost is, but not quite.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Yeah, I almost closed as a dupe, but I decided that even though the underlying issue was a dupe, this particular manifestation didn't have an obvious one I knew about. If somebody else wants to do that particular legwork, they're welcome to it. Seriously, though: you should make your comment an answer, because it's the root of the actual problem. I'll upvote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Checking for ndarray type

Preferred over `type(x)`: use `isinstance`.

From [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations):

> Object type comparisons should always use `isinstance()` instead of
>   comparing types directly.

In your example: use `if isinstance(x, np.ndarray):`

#### Checking if `x` is `None`

Option 1: 
Use `elif x is None:`.  This explicitly checks that `x` is None.

Option 2: 
Use `elif not x:`.  This takes advantage of the "Falsiness" of `None`, *but* it also would evaluate to True if `x` is other "Falsey" values such as `np.nan`, 0, or an empty data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
import numpy as np

def check(x):
    if type(x) is np.ndarray:
        print('x is numpy.ndarray')
    else:
        raise ValueError("x is None")

check(np.array([1, 2]))
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, however I'm just considering he wants to pass whether a numpy array or None!

Answer (score 0):

The reason it raises the value error is that with a recent enough version of Numpy the [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) override of arrays does an elementwise object comparison even when comparing to None.

With Numpy 1.12.1:

```
In [2]: if np.array([1,2,3]) == None:
   ...:     print('Equals None')
   ...: else:
   ...:     print('Does not equal None')
   ...:     
/home/user/Work/SO/bin/ipython:1: FutureWarning: comparison to `None` will result in an elementwise object comparison in the future.
  #!/home/user/Work/SO/bin/python3
Does not equal None
```

and with Numpy 1.13.1:

```
In [1]: if np.array([1,2,3]) == None:
   ...:     print('Equals None')
   ...: else:
   ...:     print('Does not equal None')
   ...:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-06133f6732e1> in <module>()
----> 1 if np.array([1,2,3]) == None:
      2     print('Equals None')
      3 else:
      4     print('Does not equal None')
      5 

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The error is quite self explanatory. Numpy has a different view on truthiness of an array compared to how plain Python sequences behave.

In order to check if an object is the [singleton value None](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#None), you should use [identity comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is) as also explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247373/python-none-comparison-should-i-use-is-or):

```
def check(x):
    if x is None:
        print('x is None')

    else:
        print('x is not None')
```