# How to find a value from a Binary Search Tree in python?

Tags: python-3.x, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I want to create a interactive Binary Search Tree(BST). So I created the BST using the following code as

```
class BTreeNode(object):
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.rChild = None
    self.lChild = None

  def __str__(self):
    return (self.lChild.__str__() + '<-' if self.lChild != None 
    else '') + self.data.__str__() + (
    '->' + self.rChild.__str__() if self.rChild != None else '')

  # Insert method to create nodes
  def insert(self, btreeNode):
    if self.data > btreeNode.data:  # insert left
        if self.lChild == None:
            self.lChild = btreeNode
        else:
            self.lChild.insert(btreeNode)
    else:  # insert right
        if self.rChild == None:
            self.rChild = btreeNode
        else:
            self.rChild.insert(btreeNode)
  # Insert method to create nodes

  # findval method to compare the value with nodes
  def findval(self, lkpval):
    if lkpval < self.data:
        if self.lChild.data is None:
            return str(lkpval)+" Not Found"
        return self.lChild.findval(lkpval)
    elif lkpval > self.data:
        if self.rChild.data is None:
            return str(lkpval)+" Not Found"
        return self.rChild.findval(lkpval)
    else:
        print(str(self.data) + ' is found')
  # findval method to compare the value with nodes

def display():
 btreeRoot = BTreeNode(5)
 print('inserted %s:' % 5, btreeRoot)

 btreeRoot.insert(BTreeNode(7))
 print('inserted %s:' % 7, btreeRoot)

 btreeRoot.insert(BTreeNode(3))
 print('inserted %s:' % 3, btreeRoot)

 btreeRoot.insert(BTreeNode(1))
 print('inserted %s:' % 1, btreeRoot)

 # print(btreeRoot.findval(3))

print(display())
```

If I execute the above code I will get the following interactive output as

> inserted 5: 5
>
> inserted 7: 5->7
>
> inserted 3: 3<-5->7
>
> inserted 1: 1<-3<-5->7

This is the my expected output and I got it. Also, I want to find a value from the BST. So I used the following code in the display function as

```
# print(btreeRoot.findval(3))
```

If I un comment the code I will get error. So, how can I modify my code to display whether 3 is present in the BST or not? Thanks..

Comment: I get no errors running this code. Could you provide a traceback, please?

Comment: Please find the unknown value in the BST. For ex.  print(btreeRoot.findval(33)) . This time it shows error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs when you perform checks `if self.lChild.data is None` and `if self.rChild.data is None`. These lines should be replaced by `if self.lChild is None` and `if self.rChild is None` respectively, as your class implies those attributes being `None`'s, not their `data` attributes.

Also consider using `is None` instead `== None`. This is not a big problem in this case, but may cause troubles in other contexts. Look here for details: [Python None comparison: should I use "is" or ==?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247373/python-none-comparison-should-i-use-is-or)

Comment: As per your guidelines now its working.. Thank you very much reartnew..