# Stopping a loop when value = None

Tags: python

I have a function that adds API requests to a list, I would like to loop over the requests until the value of 'next_page' is None. My current code is returning the error:

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

When I print out my results I see that my function is trying to concatenate a 'None' value - how can I stop it doing this? I've tried adding in another if statement `if next_page != 'None':` but I am still getting the same result.

Here is my function:

```
pages = []
def build_requests(request):
    request = 'https://api.performancehorizon.com' + request
    job = requests.get(request, headers=headers, params=params)
    req = job.json()

    hypermedia_np = req['hypermedia']['pagination']['next_page']

    pages.append(request)

    while hypermedia_np is not None or hypermedia_np != 'None':
        next_page = req['hypermedia']['pagination']['next_page']
        print(next_page)

        if next_page != 'None':
            pages.append(next_page)
        job = requests.get('https://api.performancehorizon.com' + next_page, headers=headers, params=params)
        req = job.json()
        hypermedia_np = req['hypermedia']['pagination']['next_page']
    print("Done!")
```

Comment: just use `if next_page:`? You also need to push job variable under the `if` condition

Comment: Or use `if next_page is not None:`. With `if next_page:`, you will also omit the case where `next_page` is an empty string (`''`), which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Why are you checking for a string with the word 'None' instead of the actual `None`?

Comment: @LevM. I am getting the same results using `if next_page is not None:`

Comment: @BenP what line exactly do you get the error on?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you want to achieve here, but you should put the following lines into the if statement too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your if statement `hypermedia_np != 'None':` and `if next_page != 'None':`
, `'None'` is a string of four characters. You are appending every `next_page` except the four-letter-string `'None'`. The real `None` object (of `NoneType`) is accepted by the condition.

So either write:

`if next_page is not None:`

to compare `next_page` against a `None` object, (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247373/python-none-comparison-should-i-use-is-or) for the reason you should not use `!=` to compare against `None`.)

or

`if next_page:`

if you also want to exclude an empty string(`''`) from being accepted. This relies on the logic that both `None` and `''` is converted to boolean `False`.

---

(Edit to address more)

Also, if you want to properly handle `None` values for `next_page` you should also put the following line(s) into the if statement. See your next line:

```py
job = requests.get('https://api.performancehorizon.com' + next_page, headers=headers, params=params)
```

You don't want to add `next_page` to the URL string, if `next_page is None`, do you?