# if condition not met but still prints "if" in nested if statements with for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

Why does this code never goes in to "else" and print accordingly when the condition in "if" is not satisfied?

```
j=0
for i in data:
  if j<10:

    if i['product']['id'] == p_id:
        if (i['stop_price']!='None'):
            print("Order Type:" +  str(i['stop_order_type']))
            print("Stop Price: " + str(i['stop_price']))

        else:
            print("Order Type: " + str(i['order_type']))



        print("Limit Price: " + str(i['limit_price']))
        print("Side: " + str(i['side']))
        print("Size: " + str(i['size']))
        print("Unfilled Size: " + str(i['unfilled_size']))

        print("\n\n")

    j+=1
```

It prints the below output:

```
Order Type:stop_loss_order
Stop Price: 405.0
Limit Price: 400.0
Side: buy
Size: 1
Unfilled Size: 1



Order Type:None
Stop Price: None
Limit Price: 280.0
Side: sell
Size: 1
Unfilled Size: 0



Order Type:None
Stop Price: None
Limit Price: 300.0
Side: sell
Size: 1
Unfilled Size: 1
```

But the correct Output should be:

```
Order Type:stop_loss_order
Stop Price: 405.0
Limit Price: 400.0
Side: buy
Size: 1
Unfilled Size: 1



Order Type:Limit
Limit Price: 280.0
Side: sell
Size: 1
Unfilled Size: 0



Order Type:Limit
Limit Price: 300.0
Side: sell
Size: 1
Unfilled Size: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `'None'` to a bare `None`.  You're comparing it to the string `'None'`, which is generally going to be `False` unless it actually *is* the string `'None'`.

It should look like:

```
    if (i['stop_price'] != None):
```

Note that in the case of a comparison with `None`, it's slightly more efficient to do:

```
    if (i['stop_price'] is not None):
```

Thierry Lathuille points out that the latter is recommended by the [PEP 8 Programming Recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations).  Both versions should behave the same.

Comment: You should rather do `if (i['stop_price'] is not None):`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247373/python-none-comparison-should-i-use-is-or

Comment: @ThierryLathuille They're equivalent in the case of `None`, although `is not` is probably a little faster.  I was addressing the specific problem that prevented OP's code from running, and I didn't want to confuse the issue by changing the comparison operator.

Comment: I understand why you left it the way it was - maybe you could add the 'canonical' way to do it to your answer.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Ok, I added a note per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value and type of i['stop_price'] in line if (i['stop_price']!='None') and modify the condition accordingly.

Here you are trying to check the value of i['stop_price'] not to be equal to 'None' of type String which can always be True unless the actual value in i['stop_price'] is equal to 'None' of type String.