BST Delete node method removes entire subtree. Python
I'm struggling getting my Delete function to work for my BST class, I mostly understand the idea behind but can't quite get the implementation right.
Here in DataStructures.py I have a class for the BST, it pulls from another class DataStructures which just takes in a list of arguments for values.
# Class for Binary Search Tree (BST)
class BST(DataStructures):
    
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.root = None
        for arg in args:
            self.insert(arg)

    # Function to insert into tree
    def insert(self, data):
        new_node = self.BSTNode(data)
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = new_node
        else:
            current_node = self.root
            while current_node != None:
                if current_node.data < new_node.data:
                    if current_node.right is None:
                        current_node.right = new_node
                        return
                    else:
                        current_node = current_node.right
                elif current_node.data > new_node.data:
                    if current_node.left is None:
                        current_node.left = new_node
                        return
                    else:
                        current_node = current_node.left

    # Function to search BST
    def search(self, value):
        node = self.root
        count = 1
        if node is None:
            print("Tree is Empty")
        elif value == node.data:
            print(f"{value} in line {count} of tree.")
        else:
            while node != None and node.data != value:
                count +=1
                if node.data < value:
                    node = node.right
                elif node.data > value:
                    node = node.left
            if node is None:
                print(f"{value} Not in Tree")
            else:
                print(f"{value} in line {count} of tree.")

    # Function to get min value in BST
    def getMin(self, node = "root"):
        if node == "root":
            node = self.root
        min = node.data
        while node.left != None:
            min = node.left.data
            node = node.left
        return min

    # Function to get max value in BST
    def getMax(self, node = "root"):
        if node == "root":
            node = self.root
        max = node.data
        while node.right != None:
            max = node.right.data
            node = node.right
        return max

    # Function to delete a node in BST
    def delNode(self, value, node = "root"):
        if node == "root":
            node = self.root
        if node is None:
            return node
        if value < node.data:
            node.left = self.delNode(value, node.left)
        elif value > node.data:
            node.right = self.delNode(value, node.right)
        else:
            if node.left is None:
                return node.right
            elif node.right is None:
                return node.left
            node.data = self.getMin(node.right)
            node.right = self.delNode(node.data, node.right)
            return node

    # Function to traverse in-order BST
    def inOrder(self, node = "root"):
        if node == "root":
            node = self.root
        if node:                    # Recursively print left-right most nodes on tree
            self.inOrder(node.left)
            print(node.data, end=" ")
            self.inOrder(node.right)

    # Function to get BST height
    def getHeight(self, node = "root"):
        if node == "root":
            node = self.root
        if node is None:
            return 0
        leftHeight = self.getHeight(node.left)      # Recursively get height of left/right nodes then return the larger
        rightHeight = self.getHeight(node.right)    # of them, adding 1 to their increment each time, 
        return max(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1

    # Function to see if BST is balanced
    def getBalance(self, node = "root"):
        if node == "root":
            node = self.root
        if node is None:
            return True
        left_height = self.getHeight(node.left)     # Get height from either side of our root node
        right_height = self.getHeight(node.right)
        if((left_height - right_height) > 1 or (left_height - right_height) < -1):
            return False
        left_balance = self.getBalance(node.left)   # Check if each subtree is balanced, return True if so
        right_balance = self.getBalance(node.right)
        if left_balance == True and right_balance == True:
            return True

    # String Method for BST see repr function in BSTNode Class
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        if self.root is None:
           return "Tree is Empty"
        else:
            return repr(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.root)
            
    # Class for Nodes of the BST
    class BSTNode():
        def __init__(self, data):
            self.data = data
            self.left = None
            self.right = None

        # Return String Representation of BST (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62407035)
        def __repr__(self):
            lines = []
            if self.right:
                found = False
                for line in repr(self.right).split("\n"):
                    if line[0] != " ":
                        found = True
                        line = " ┌─" + line
                    elif found:
                        line = " | " + line
                    else:
                        line = "   " + line
                    lines.append(line)
            lines.append(str(self.data))
            if self.left:
                found = False
                for line in repr(self.left).split("\n"):
                    if line[0] != " ":
                        found = True
                        line = " └─" + line
                    elif found:
                        line = "   " + line
                    else:
                        line = " | " + line
                    lines.append(line)
            return "\n".join(lines)

And here is my main.py with various tests while I coded the BST
import DataStructures

bst = DataStructures.BST(4, 2, 6, 3, 1, 5, 8, 10)

# bst.insert(10)
# bst.insert(5)
# bst.search(0)
# print(bst.getMax())
# bst.inOrder()
# print(bst.getHeight())
# print(bst.getBalance())
# print(bst)
bst.delNode(8)
print(bst)
bst.inOrder()

After trying for a while myself and getting nowhere I attempted implementing code from other stackoverflow questions and various other outlets but couldn't get it to overwrite the correct node. In my main.py example only the 8 node should be removed but I always end up with all of the right tree deleted
Output from main.py:
4
 |  ┌─3
 └─2
    └─1
1 2 3 4


Please post a [mre]. We don't need the methods that are unrelated to adding and deleting nodes, like getHeight() and getBalance().

Some of the branches in delNode() return a value, some don't. You should be consistent -- does this return something or does it modify in place?

What's supposed to happen when deleting "root"? Assigning to the local variable node has no effect.

When you recurse into the left or right nodes, you're not returning anything. If this came from a call that was recursing into a left or right node, it will set that node to None. You always need to return something.
    def delNode(self, value, node = "root"):
        if node == "root":
            return self.root
        if node is None:
            return node
        if value < node.data:
            node.left = self.delNode(value, node.left)
            return node
        elif value > node.data:
            node.right = self.delNode(value, node.right)
            return node
        else:
            if node.left is None:
                return node.right
            elif node.right is None:
                return node.left
            node.data = self.getMin(node.right)
            node.right = self.delNode(node.data, node.right)
            return node

