# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable for circle detection with opencv

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to detect circles from my webcam input and draw over the detected objects using this code:

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(roi_gray2, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)

for i in circles[0,:]:
    cv2.circle(roi_color2, tuple(i[0]), tuple(i[1]), (255,255,255), 1)
```

it leads to this error:

```
    for i in circles[0,:]:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I'm guessing it runs into this error when the object 'circles' is empty. So I want the for loop to run only when there are elements in the 'circles' object. How do I do this?

Comment: I tried using "if circles != None:" before the for loop but it shows this error "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Comment: Comparing to `None` is done by `is None` or `is not None`. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247373/python-none-comparison-should-i-use-is-or

Comment: @Gulzar i edited the code and wrote "if circles is not None:" and the loop works now. Thanks! (I still have errors in the circle drawing function though, commented below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual error comes from the [`tuple()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tuple-function/) function which expects an iterable. Since you're passing a single value `i[0]`, this function call fails with the given error message. At this point, it doesn't matter, whether `circles` has proper values or is just `None`.

So, the first step is, as also stated in [Gulzar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65337940/11089932), to check whether `circles` is `None`. But, this doesn't solve the actual error coming from the `tuple()` call. Therefore, check the OpenCV documentation on [`circle`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#gaf10604b069374903dbd0f0488cb43670): The `center` needs to be a tuple of two `int` values, and `radius` a single `int` value. So, just get rid of the `tuple()` calls and set up the tuple manually:

```py
if circles is not None:
    for i in circles[0, :]:
        cv2.circle(roi_color2, (int(i[0]), int(i[1])), int(i[2]), (255,255,255), 1)
```

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.5
OpenCV:      4.4.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Okay yeah I used the tuple because I ran into another error. I fixed it now and the code works! Thank you so much <3

Answer (score 1):

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(roi_gray2, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)

if circles is not None:
    for i in circles[0,:]:
        cv2.circle(roi_color2, tuple(i[0]), tuple(i[1]), (255,255,255), 1)
```

Is a workaround like you requested.

---

However, it would make MUCH more sense to avoid this situation altogether.
Ask yourself why `circles` is `None` in the first place.

I am assuming there is a previous problem with `roi_gray2` that causes `cv2.HoughCircles` to fail.

Since you didn't provide full code or details, I can't say, but I would check this if I were you, instead of checking for None before the loop. You are just avoiding a consequence rather than the problem itself.

This `None` test will repeat throughhout your code, instead of solving the origin.

Comment: That only fixes half of the problem. You'd also need to modify the `circle` call to something like `cv2.circle(roi_color2, (int(i[0]), int(i[1])), int(i[2]), (255,255,255), 1)`, cf. the OpenCV documentation on [`circle`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#gaf10604b069374903dbd0f0488cb43670).

Comment: And, to be precise, the error comes from the `tuple` call which expects an iterable. So, in fact, checking for `i` to be iterable solves the actual error. Nevertheless, the usage of `tuple` along with a single value here is questionable at all.