# While loop exit condition not working properly

Tags: python

So I'm trying to run a while loop, which should ideally stop when `winner` is either `True` or `False`. The `table.isWinner()` method returns either one of these values. But the loop for some reason is not getting stopped, until `outerCount` is bigger than `tableColNum*tableRowNum` (the other condition).

```
            tableRowNum = table.getNumRows()
            tableColNum = table.getNumColumns()
            stackNum = table.getNumStacks()
            winner = None
            outerCount = 0
            while winner == None and outerCount < tableColNum*tableRowNum:
                for i in range(tableRowNum):
                    for j in range(tableColNum):
                        domino = table.select(i, j)
                        played = None
                        count = 0
                        while count < stackNum and not played:
                            played = table.playDomino(domino, count)
                            count += 1
                        print(table)
                        winner = table.isWinner()
                        print(winner)
                        outerCount += 1
```

Comment: The *outer* loop condition won't be checked again until *after* all the inner loops also end (or break).

Comment: FYI you should use `is None` rather than `== None`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247373/python-none-comparison-should-i-use-is-or

Comment: Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops) is quite relevant to your issue and goes into how you can solve it.

Comment: It seems like you intend the inner for loops to stop *immediately*, *as soon as* the `winner` value gets set to something other than `None`. Yes? Loops don't work that way. The loop condition is only checked at the top of the loop, not continuously.

Comment: By the inner loops, do you mean the for loops? Because the inner `while` loop does end when `.iswinner()` is evaluated and set to `winner`.

Comment: OHHH I see. Dear lord I had this basic understanding wrong. Thank you so much!