# How do I resolve this error output: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python

This code reads my humidity sensor that is connected to a raspberry pi:

```
while True:
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(DHT_SENSOR, DHT_PIN)

    if humidity<50:
        temp_f = temperature * 1.8 + 32
        table = [["Status", "Low Humidity"],["Humidity","{1:0.1f}%".format(temp_f, humidity)],["Temp","{0:0.1f}*F".format(temp_f, humidity)]]
        print(tabulate(table))
        time.sleep(3)
    elif humidity > 75:
        temp_f = temperature * 1.8 + 32
        table = [["Status", "High Humidity"],["Humidity","{1:0.1f}%".format(temp_f, humidity)],["Temp","{0:0.1f}*F".format(temp_f, humidity)]]
        print(tabulate(table))
        time.sleep(3)
    else:
        temp_f = temperature * 1.8 + 32
        table = [["Status", "OK"],["Humidity","{1:0.1f}%".format(temp_f, humidity)],["Temp","{0:0.1f}*F".format(temp_f, humidity)]]
        print(tabulate(table))
        time.sleep(3)
```

It works until it spits out an error:

```
$ python3 humidity1.py 
--------  ------
Status    OK
Humidity  57.7%
Temp      79.5*F
--------  ------
--------  ------
Status    OK
Humidity  53.9%
Temp      79.0*F
--------  ------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "humidity1.py", line 12, in <module>
    if humidity<50:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

What did I do wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: seems like this Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(DHT_SENSOR, DHT_PIN) is not returning the value you expect. you should check if humidity is different from None before comparing it to any other value

Comment: humidity appears to be a NoneType object, it's hard to say why. I would suggest placing print blocks in different stages of your script where you reference humidity and check where it isn't your expected value. - Debugging 101

Comment: Thank you i resolved it by adding a continue statement. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you are comparing a number to a `None` object. Since your number is not a variable the only thing able to be `None` in that line is  `humidity`

Answer (score 0):

My variables were not being assigned due to hardware. I added a continue statement which let the loop ride. I added this if statement:

```
if humidity == None or temperature == None:
            print("Variable Empty - Restarting")
            continue
```

Whole Loop:

```
while True:
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(DHT_SENSOR, DHT_PIN)

    if humidity == None or temperature == None:
        print("Variable Empty - Restarting")
        continue
    elif humidity<50:
        temp_f = temperature * 1.8 + 32
        table = [["Status", "Low Humidity"],["Humidity","{1:0.1f}%".format(temp_f, humidity)],["Temp","{0:0.1f}*F".format(temp_f, humidity)]]
        print(tabulate(table))
        time.sleep(3)
    elif humidity > 75:
        temp_f = temperature * 1.8 + 32
        table = [["Status", "High Humidity"],["Humidity","{1:0.1f}%".format(temp_f, humidity)],["Temp","{0:0.1f}*F".format(temp_f, humidity)]]
        print(tabulate(table))
        time.sleep(3)
    else:
        temp_f = temperature * 1.8 + 32
        table = [["Status", "OK"],["Humidity","{1:0.1f}%".format(temp_f, humidity)],["Temp","{0:0.1f}*F".format(temp_f, humidity)]]
        print(tabulate(table))
        time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Comparison with `None` should be done with `is`, not with `==`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247373/python-none-comparison-should-i-use-is-or