# Default function argument value for Numpy Arrays and lists

Tags: python, numpy

I want to define a function that determines whether an input to a function is a numpy array or list or the input is none of the two mentioned data types. Here is the code:

```
def test_array_is_given(arr = None):
    if arr != None:
        if type(arr) in [np.ndarray, list]:
            return True
    return False


input_junk = 12
input_list = [1,2,3,4]
input_numpy = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

print(test_array_is_given(input_junk))
print(test_array_is_given(input_list))
print(test_array_is_given(input_numpy))
```

And here is what I get:

```
False
True

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/gv/k2qrhzhn1tg5g_kcrnxpm3c80000gn/T/ipykernel_1992/766992758.py in <module>
     12 print(test_array_is_given(input_junk))
     13 print(test_array_is_given(input_list))
---> 14 print(test_array_is_given(input_numpy))

/var/folders/gv/k2qrhzhn1tg5g_kcrnxpm3c80000gn/T/ipykernel_1992/766992758.py in test_array_is_given(arr)
      1 def test_array_is_given(arr = None):
----> 2     if arr != None:
      3         if type(arr) in [np.ndarray, list]:
      4             return True
      5     return False

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

As you can see, I set the default value for argument `arr` to be `None`. However, whenever I try to evaluate the function given a numpy array, it faces the above error.

Any ideas on how to resolve this? Thank you for your attention in advance.

Comment: Comparison with `None` should be done with `is`. In this case: `if arr is not None:`

Answer (score 1):

Your function might be fixes and ameloriated using `isinstance` built-in function as follows:

```
import numpy as np
def test_array_is_given(arr=None):
    return isinstance(arr, (np.ndarray, list))
print(test_array_is_given())  # False
print(test_array_is_given(np.ones(1)))  # True
print(test_array_is_given([1,2,3]))  # True
```

when 2nd argument is tuple that might be read as *any of*, in this case check if it is `np.ndarray` of `list`. No special check for `None` is required as it is object of class `NoneType`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am wondering what to prefer, your solution or what @Matthias suggested (in comment section of the question)?

Answer (score 1):

Matthias points this out already: The issue is with the equality check `arr != None`.

When `arr` is a numpy array, `arr != None` checks if each element of arr is unequal to `None` and returns a np.array of boolean values.

```
In[1]: arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

In[2]: arr != None

Out[2]:
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
```

What you want to do is

```
In[3]: arr is not None
Out[3]: True
```

Generally if you want to check if a values is not None. Use: `val is not None`.

Comment: Thank you. you draw a good example of what != means for for numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Matthias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1209921/matthias), I learnt about my problem.
That is, I have to compare objects with `None` using `is`.

Now that I know about `is` operator, I found a [stackoverflow question\answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247373/python-none-comparison-should-i-use-is-or) which explains why we should choose `is` over `==` (or `is not` over `!=`).

Note: the good news is that `is not` also works for my case; that is, replacing it with `!=` returns my expected values (`False`, `True` and `True` respectively).