# When trying to append to a list, I get the error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'"

Tags: python, recursion, search

This is supposed to be a program in Python which returns the position of a target element in a list recursively:

```
def linear_search_arrayList(arr, target, arr2 = [], num = 0):
    if(len(arr) == num):
        return arr2
    elif(arr[num]==target):
        return linear_search_arrayList(arr,target, arr2.append(num) , num+1)
    else:
        return linear_search_arrayList(arr,target, arr2, num +1)
    
    
array_list = [1,2,3,4,6,7,4,9]
print(linear_search_arrayList(array_list, 4))
```

This program returns an error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and *ask a question*.

Comment: `append` doesn't return the updated list. Recursion is a terrible way to implement a loop in Python, whether or not you use tail recursion, because Python doesn't perform tail-call optimization.

Comment: Using `[]` as the default argument value also means that *every* call to your function is going to see the values added to `arr2` by previous calls.

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are passing to `linear_search_arrayList` the `arr2.append(num)` argument, witch returns `None`, so you are passing the `None` argument to the function, since you cannot append a value to a `NoneType` object, you cannot pass that.

if your purpose was to add to the list and then pass it through the function, you can do:

```
def linear_search_arrayList(arr, target, arr2 = [], num = 0):

    if(len(arr) == num):
        return arr2
    elif(arr[num]==target):
        return linear_search_arrayList(arr,target, arr2+[num] , num+1)
    else:
        return linear_search_arrayList(arr,target, arr2, num +1)
    
    
array_list = [1,2,3,4,6,7,4,9]
print(linear_search_arrayList(array_list, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code had several issues.

1. The name `linear_search_arrayList` does not fit Python's style guidelines; functions have lowercase names (in the [snake_case format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case))
2. You had unnecessary parentheses in your `if` an `elif` statements.
3. Having `arr2 = None` in your function arguments means that `arr2` will always point to the *same list*, which is generated once the moment the program is run. If you want it to be a new, empty list every time, you have to explicitly create a new list. A good practice for this is to set the default value to `None`, then check for that with `is None`. You should not do `== None` because that is not good practice in Python ([explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247373/python-none-comparison-should-i-use-is-or)).
4. The `append` error was happening because `append` returns nothing; it affects the original list. If you want to append something to a list, you can either do it beforehand like `arr2.append(num)`, or do `arr2 + [num]` if you don't want to affect `arr2`.

With all that in mind, here is my attempt at fixing your code; you'll have to determine if it functions how you want, though.

```
def linear_search_array_list(arr, target, arr2=None, num=0):
    if arr2 is None:
        arr2 = []
    if len(arr) == num:
        return arr2
    elif arr[num] == target:
        return linear_search_array_list(arr, target, arr2 + [num], num + 1)
    else:
        return linear_search_array_list(arr, target, arr2, num + 1)


array_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 4, 9]
print(linear_search_array_list(array_list, 4))
```