# Trying Python's "None" in a "if" statement, but i cant print the message: "print("Any value.!")" comparing None with an empty Value, why i cant?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
value = None

print("Insert a value:")
value = input()

if value == None:
    print("Any value.!")
else:
    print("Your value is different to None: ", value)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python None comparison: should I use "is" or ==?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247373/python-none-comparison-should-i-use-is-or)

Comment: `if value is None:`

Comment: It won't work anyways, since `input` can't return None. If you don't input anything it will return `''`

Comment: @Nick, the return of `input` is always a string.  The if-statement will always be False because `value` will never be `None`.

Comment: @James yeah, vtc'd only after looking at the comparison test...

Answer (score 4):

When you assign `value = input()`, `value` will now be a string.  Even if the user does not provide an input (just hits enter), the value will be an empty string `''`.  So comparing to `None` will always fail.

Instead, just check if the value is not empty using `if value:`

```py
print("Insert a value:")
value = input()

if value:
    print("Any value.!")
else:
    print("Your value is different to None: ", value)
```