# same_row = self.row == other.row AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'row' with gspread

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to program a discord bot that links to google sheets but have been encountering countless errors with my code.
The error I get is as followed:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Bundeswehr-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ui/modal.py", line 186, in _scheduled_task
    await self.on_submit(interaction)
  File "/home/runner/Bundeswehr-Bot/modals.py", line 45, in on_submit
    if sheet.find(self.host.value) == None:
  File "/home/runner/Bundeswehr-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gspread/cell.py", line 44, in __eq__
    same_row = self.row == other.row
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'row'
```

And my code is:

```py
class bct_modal(discord.ui.Modal, title="BCT Logging"):
  host = discord.ui.TextInput(
        label='Host ID',
        placeholder='The hosts discord ID here...',
        required=True
    )

  async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
      ids = []
      ids.append(self.host.value)

      print(ids)
      if sheet.find(self.host.value) == None:
        sheet.append_row([self.host.value, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
        for id in ids:
          bct_host_col = sheet.find("Hosted BCT").col
          cell_row = sheet.find(id).row
          sheet.update_cell(cell_row, bct_host_col, int(sheet.cell(cell_row, bct_host_col).value) + 1)
      elif sheet.find(self.host.value) != None:
        print("This ID is already in the sheet.")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**NOTE:** When I input an ID that isn't yet in the google spreadsheet, it appends it perfectly and just the way I want it, but if I try enter an ID that's already in the spreadsheet, it throws me this error.

Comment: Hi, the error happens because the value of `value` in `self.host.value` is `None`. so when gspread tries to find the value it cannot compare `None` to something else.

Comment: @Lavigne958 Hi, thanks for the response. That confuses me quite a lot because I enter in a value for ```self.host.value``` in the discord modal. Only if the input value is already in the spreadsheet, it throws me that error. If not, the code does what it's supposed to do (append a new row into the spreadsheet with the value given).

Answer (score 5):

In your script, I thought that `if sheet.find(self.host.value) == None:` might be required to be modified. So, `==` is `is`. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue of `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'row'`.

I thought that in this case, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14247373) might be useful.

So, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
if sheet.find(self.host.value) == None:
```

#### To:

```
if sheet.find(self.host.value) is None:
```

- When I tested your script, I could replicate the same issue with you. And, when this modification is reflected in the script, I confirmed that the error was removed.

#### Reference:

- Related thread: [Python None comparison: should I use "is" or ==?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14247373)

The reason this is important in this case is that Python translates `x == y` to `x.__eq__(y)` if an `__eq__` method exists for `x`'s class, and the gspread `Cell` class implements a custom `__eq__` method that attempts unguarded attribute access on the `other` object (`other.row`), which can have unexpected results if `other` is not a `Cell` (in this case, it throws an error, but passing in another class that does have a `row` attribute might behave differently).

While this is very bad practice on the part of the gspread developers, it is avoided if you use `is` as a rule for comparisons against `None`.