# Remove empty dicts in nested dictionary with recursive function

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to remove non-values from a nested dictionary.  My first effort works fine, but unfortunately keys pointing to now empty dicts still persist.

So if i do:

```
pass1 = stripper(my_dict)
return stripper(pass1)
```

This works, but i'm thinking a more elegant nested solution might be possible?

```
def stripper(self, data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        d = ({k: stripper(v) for k, v in data.items()
             if v not in [u'', None]})
        if d:
            return d
    else:
        return data
```

Edit:

Failing example, dict below returns as `{'foo': 'bar', 'bar': None}`:

```
{
    'foo': 'bar',
    'bar': {
        'foo': None,
        'one': None
    }
}
```

Comment: you usually dont pass my_dict to strippers... that doesnt end well

Comment: Can you post a very simple example where this doesn't work?  If it leaves empty dicts on the first pass, then it seems likely that subsequent passes could leave keys with empty values as well...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The dict comprehension is certainly concise but if you expand it out, the solution becomes more obvious:

```
def stripper(self, data):
    new_data = {}
    for k, v in data.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            v = stripper(v)
        if not v in (u'', None, {}):
            new_data[k] = v
    return new_data
```

Comment: Was missing the `{}` in the `not v in ('', None, {})` line - I hadn't tested it. Added that and it appears to me to work. Whomever down-voted, take another look as I believe this does the trick.

Comment: Flake8 nags me to say, that third to last line should be `if v not in (u'', None, {}):`

Answer (score 4):

To extend the accepted answer to include objects that might be an element of a list:

```
def clean_empties(value: dict | list) -> dict | list:
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        value = {
            k: v
            for k, v in ((k, clean_empties(v)) for k, v in value.items())
            if v
        }
    elif isinstance(value, list):
        value = [v for v in (clean_empties(v) for v in value) if v]
    return value
        

# Usage:
data = {
    "None": None,
    "empty_list": [],
    "empty_dict": {},
    "empty_string": "",
    "list_with_empties": [
        "",
        {},
        [],
        None,
        {
            "more_empties": "",
            "and_even_more": [""],
            "one_thing_i_care_about": "hi",
        },
    ],
}
# Or alternatively data can be a list
# data = ['', {}, [], None, {'more_empties': '', 'and_even_more': [''], 'one_thing_i_care_about': 'hi'}]
cleaned = clean_empties(data)
print(cleaned)
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer of @Oliver is correct, but having some edge cases checks won't hurt, here you go: (Was unable to edit Oliver's answer as the queue was full)

```py
    def dictionary_stripper(data):
        new_data = {}
        
        # Only iterate if the given dict is not None
        if data:
            for k, v in data.items():
                if isinstance(v, dict):
                    v = dictionary_stripper(v)
                
                # ideally it should be not in, second you can also add a empty list if required
                if v not in ("", None, {}, []):
                    new_data[k] = v
            
            # Only if you want the root dict to be None if empty
            if new_data == {}:
                return None
            return new_data
        return None
```

Comment: CampaignAdminUtils?

Comment: @chrisinmtown Thanks for pointing this out. Left the class name by mistake, ideally that should be recursion, so it should be just `dictionary_stripper`

Answer (score 0):

I landed here with a need to drop None values yet preserve empty dicts and lists. Reused/modified @OliverDain answer, thanks for that. Hope this helps someone.

```
def drop_none_values(data):
    """
    Recursively remove None values in a dictionary or list;
    this includes list of dicts, etc. Do not drop empty
    dicts or lists.

    :param data: Object to process for None values.
        Returns a new dict if passed a dict;
        returns a new list if passed a list;
        returns the argument unchanged otherwise.
    """
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        new_data = {}
        for k, v in data.items():
            v = drop_none_values(v)
            if v is not None:
                new_data[k] = v
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        new_data = []
        for v in data:
            v = drop_none_values(v)
            if v is not None:
                new_data.append(v)
    else:
        new_data = data
    return new_data
```

Here's my test case, that function above is in a file/module named `util`:

```
def test_drop_none_values():
    data = {
        'first': None,
        'second': None,
        'empty': [],
        'alist': ['string', None, {'foo': None, 'bar': 'baz'}]
    }
    assert len(data) == 4
    stripped = util.drop_none_values(data)
    assert len(stripped) == 2
    assert len(stripped['alist']) == 2
    assert len(stripped['alist'][1]) == 1
```