# Remove NULL, FALSE, and '' - but not 0 - from a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

I want to remove `NULL`, `FALSE` and `''` values .

I used `array_filter` but it removes the `0`' s also.

Is there any function to do what I want?

```
array(NULL,FALSE,'',0,1) -> array(0,1)
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

[`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) should work fine if you use the [**`identical` comparison operator**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

[here's an example](http://codepad.org/ppRy0PcT)

```
$values = [NULL, FALSE, '', 0, 1];

function myFilter($var){
  return ($var !== NULL && $var !== FALSE && $var !== '');
}

$res = array_filter($values, 'myFilter');
```

Or if you don't want to define a filtering function, you can also use an **anonymous function** (closure):

```
$res = array_filter($values, function($value) {
    return ($value !== null && $value !== false && $value !== ''); 
});
```

If you just need the numeric values you can use [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) as your callback: [example](http://codepad.org/MTMUkwGb)

```
$res = array_filter($values, 'is_numeric');
```

Comment: The second example is a bit dangerous, since you don't know what sort of data OP is filtering. That filter will remove much more than just `NULL`, `FALSE`, and `""`.

Comment: true, added a note to the answer.

Answer (score 66):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#111091 :

If you want to remove NULL, FALSE and Empty Strings, but leave values of 0, you can use strlen as the callback function:

```
array_filter($array, 'strlen');
```

Comment: That does actually work because strlen() casts its parameter to string- so 0 and 1 become "0" and "1", while null and false become "".

Comment: Genius! Just note that objects and arrays will be removed as well, and strlen will throw warnings about them.

Comment: As of PHP 8.1, strlen will now emit a deprecated error "strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated"

Answer (score 6):

`array_filter` doesn't work because, by default, it removes anything that is equivalent to `FALSE`, and PHP considers `0` to be equivalent to false. The [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) has this to say on the subject:

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> - the boolean FALSE itself
> - the integer 0 (zero)
> - the float 0.0 (zero)
> - the empty string, and the string "0"
> - an array with zero elements
> - an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
> - the special type NULL (including unset variables)
> - SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
>
> Every other value is considered TRUE (including any resource).

You can pass a second parameter to `array_filter` with a callback to a function you write yourself, which tells `array_filter` whether or not to remove the item.

Assuming you want to remove all FALSE-equivalent values *except* zeroes, this is an easy function to write:

```
function RemoveFalseButNotZero($value) {
  return ($value || is_numeric($value));
}
```

Then you just overwrite the original array with the filtered array:

```
$array = array_filter($array, "RemoveFalseButNotZero");
```

Comment: Or if you like lambdas:

`$array= array_filter($array, function($val) { return ($val || is_numeric($val));});`

Comment: @bmewburn You need to remove the negation. The callback returns TRUE if you want to *keep* the value. I misremembered when I wrote the answer originally.

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom callback function with array_filter. See this example, lifted from PHP manual, on how to use call back functions. The callback function in the example is filtering based on odd/even; you can write a little function to filter based on your requirements.

```
<?php
function odd($var)
{
    // returns whether the input integer is odd
    return($var & 1);
}

function even($var)
{
    // returns whether the input integer is even
    return(!($var & 1));
}

$array1 = array("a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4, "e"=>5);
$array2 = array(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

echo "Odd :\n";
print_r(array_filter($array1, "odd"));
echo "Even:\n";
print_r(array_filter($array2, "even"));
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down-voted :( Okay, perhaps the callback functions could be written differently, and perhaps it could have used the data in the post, but it likely shows a usage not considered by the OP. (I am out of votes myself ..)

Comment: It does not show exact call back because I was not in a mood to spoon feed. The answer itself says that 'The callback function in the example is filtering based on odd/even; you can write a little function to filter based on your requirements.' AND that I lifted it off from the PHP manual.

Answer (score 1):

One-liners are always nice.

```
$clean_array = array_diff(array_map('trim', $my_array), array('', NULL, FALSE));
```

**Explanation:**

- **1st parameter of `array_diff`:** The trimmed version of `$my_array`. Using `array_map`, surrounding whitespace is trimmed from every element via the `trim` function. It is good to use the trimmed version in case an element contains a string that is nothing but whitespace (i.e. tabs, spaces), which I assume would also want to be removed. You could just as easily use $my_array for the 1st parameter if you don't want to trim the elements.
- **2nd parameter of `array_diff`:** An array of items that you would like to remove from `$my_array`.
- **Output:** An array of elements that are contained in the 1st array that are not also contained in the 2nd array. In this case, because `''`, `NULL`, and `FALSE` are within the 2nd array, they can never be returned by `array_diff`.

**EDIT:**

It turns out you don't need to have `NULL` and `FALSE` in the 2nd array. Instead you can just have `''`, and it will work the same way:

```
$clean_array = array_diff(array_map('trim', $my_array), array(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

check whether it is less than 1 and greater than -1 if then dont remove it...

```
$arrayValue = (NULL,FALSE,'',0,1);
$newArray = array();
foreach($arrayValue as $value) {
    if(is_int($value) || ($value>-1 && $value <1)) {
        $newArray[] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: What if it was `array(NULL,FALSE,'hello world')`?

Comment: Will he have characters/string in it?

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_filter($var)
{
    // returns values that are neither false nor null (but can be 0)
    return ($var !== false && $var !== null && $var !== '');
}

$entry = array(
             0 => 'foo',
             1 => false,
             2 => -1,
             3 => null,
             4 => '',
             5 => 0
          );

print_r(array_filter($entry, 'my_filter'));
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [2] => -1
    [5] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use `array_filter` with the `'strlen'` parameter:

```
// removes all NULL, FALSE and Empty Strings but leaves 0 (zero) values
$result = array_filter($array, 'strlen');
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#111091

Comment: This throws errors if your array contains other arrays.

Comment: and as of PHP 8.1, `strlen` will now emit a deprecated error "strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated"

Answer (score -2):

```
function ExtArray($linksArray){
    foreach ($linksArray as $key => $link)
    {
        if ($linksArray[$key] == '' || $linksArray[$key] == NULL || $linksArray[$key] == FALSE || $linksArray[$key] == '')
        {
            unset($linksArray[$key]);
        }else {
            return $linksArray[$key];
        }
    }
}
```

This function may help you

Comment: This is ugly and it will have the same problem as OP had. You have to use the [**identical comparison operator**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). Good solution have 3 lines at most and you don't even have to define a function.