# Remove comma from string in php

Tags: php

suppose the value is

`1,2,,4,5,6` - For this i can use `str_replace(",,",",",$mystring)` to get `1,2,4,5,6`

How to get values like `2,4,5,6` from `,2,,4,5,6` where two or more consecutive commas are replaced by a single comma and if comma comes before any value it is neglected.If there is only commas like `,,,,,,` then empty value is returned.

how to do this in php.

Comment: Try this : str_replace( ',,', ',',  1,2,,4,5,6);

Comment: Just out of curiosity, were does that string come from? Maybe the problem is how that string is created. Isn't it possible that there could be three commas between numbers? In that case it will only replace one pair of commas and leave two commas.

Comment: this comma separated value come from input boxes with same name.i save their values using commas.if any input is empty then string will have a empty place followed by comma again.so whenever i need to prefill those values i just run the loop.In preview i have to show only actual value.

Answer (score 8):

You can `explode` the string by comma first and then `implode` after filtering the empty strings.

```
$val=",2,,4,5,6";
$parts=explode(",",$val);
$parts=array_filter($parts);
echo(implode(",",$parts));
```

Note that this will also filter `0` from your values. If you want to keep the zeros, refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134006/remove-null-false-and-but-not-0-from-a-php-array)

Comment: Note that `array_filter` may remove zeroes as well. I'm not sure if the OP wants zeroes or not.

Answer (score 4):

You can do what you did on your first problem...

Then use [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove unnecessary commas at the front or end of the string.

```
$mystring = ',2,,4,5,6';

$output = str_replace(',,', ',', $mystring);

echo trim($output, ',');

//Output will be: 2,4,5,6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Variable Declaration for String
$str = "1,2,,4,5,6";

// Create Array Out of the String, The comma ',' is the delimiter
// This would output 
//       [ 1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => '', 4 => 4, 5 => 5, 6 => 6 ]
$explodedStr = explode(',', $str);

// Filter Array And Remove The empty element which in this case
//    3 => ''
$filteredArray = array_filter( $explodedStr );

// Convert Array into String with comma delimiter 
$formattedString = implode(',',  $filteredArray);
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

1. Trim all commas from the front and back of the string because they are not useful delimiters.
2. Match one or more commas that occur immediately after a comma.

In my pattern, I match a comma, then forget it with `\K`, then match one or more commas.  These extra commas are then replaced with an empty string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/HhXJI))

```
$string = ',1,2,,4,5,,,,6,,,,';
echo preg_replace('/,\K,+/', '', trim($string, ','));
// 1,2,4,5,6
```