# Store numeric zero in an array

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I'm having problems because it's not possible to store a numeric "0" in an array.

In my case a "POST" request sends sometimes a zero as the value which I need to use in the "Limit" clause of a MySQL query.

This causes problems for me because I dynamically generate the "binding types" and "binding params" for the prepared statement. I store the "binding params" in an array and the "0" gets ignored so the query can't be executed.

Is there any workaround how to store a zero in an array or what would be the best way to handle it in my code?

**Edit**

`$_POST['start']` is always part of the binding paramaters. Is there any solution to make this position a "fixed" one and the other parameters dynamically generated out of the `$bindparamsarray`?

**Code:**

```
$classid = "4";
$start = $_POST['start']; // always an integer, but can be a 0
$length = $_POST['length'];

$bindparamsarray = [$classid, $start, $length];

$bindparams = array_filter($bindparamsarray);

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlitemsparse . $sqlitemsparse2);

$types = str_repeat('s', count($bindparams));
$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$bindparams);
$stmt->execute();
$resultitemsparse = $stmt->get_result();
```

Comment: $_POST['start']; always integer right?

Comment: Yes, it's always an int.

Comment: If its always an integer why are you binding it as a string? In your $types you set the types to 's'. If you know exactly what your parameters are and their types, why do you try to do this "Dynamically" as it's not needed.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw There are more variables which are generated dynamically depending on the users' input.  I've just shorten the code. But what I know is that `$start` and `$length` will always be part of the paramaters as integers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27501297/2943403

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks, that was the solution.